# How to install a current version of TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing

TikZ is undergoing lots of development with new features being added, but the versions distributed with standard TeX releases are often a little old. How do I get the latest version? If I want to be sure that I get the latest stable version, how do I do that?

---

Note: I'm not asking this question for myself, but because a question like this seems to be useful for pointing to it when a new feature of TikZ is mentioned in an answer to some other question. Feel free to post answers for any operating system/TeX distribution combination.

Comment: I was about to complain about a broken link since the only link is to the main page on texample and not to a specific picture!  Then I realised that it wasn't a real question.  I think this is a very good thing to have on this site, but I'm not convinced by the "fake question" style.  Why not simply, "TikZ is undergoing lots of development with new features being added, but the versions distributed with standard TeX releases are often a little old.  How do I get the latest version?  If I want to be sure that I get the latest _stable_ version, how do I do that?"

Comment: @Andrew: you are right. I changed the text. Feel free to add further changes.

Comment: I just noticed that the accepted answer is not topped -- presumably because questioner and respondent are identical. I have added a copy of your answer (CWed) and suggest you accept my answer instead.

Comment: It would be great if someone could update this answer with info about 3.0!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unless you want to use a development version of TikZ or are stuck with an old TeX distribution, **do not** manually install TikZ. Simply updating your TeX distribution should give you the newest stable release of TikZ, see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)

Of course, if you want to get a development version, follow the appropriate answer here.

Comment: My tikz-cd seems NOT up-to-date but updating my TexLive it says "no updates available".  What should I do?

Comment: If you do not have a complete TeX distribution installed, TikZ can be installed through the associated package manager, e.g. [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016).

Answer (score 27):

The tikz offical update cycle is rather slow. However, development goes on and the latest build can be found here ([tikz builds](http://www.texample.net/tikz/builds/)). The build has to be installed manually, but comes in the correct tex-tree-structure already.

For Windows users who use MikTeX, it is advisable to create a local-tree to install packages which are not available in the MkTeX package browser.

1. Download the latest build from the link above
2. Create a new folder e.g `C:\LocalTexFiles`
3. Copy the downloaded zip-file in this folder and unpack it
   You should now have two new folders in `C:\LocalTexFiles`, namely '`tex`' and '`doc`'
4. Go to *Start*->*Program Files*->*MikTeX2.x*->*Settings (Administrator)*
5. In the settings window click the *Root* tab, click *Add* and browse to `C:\LocalTexFiles` and select it, confirm by clicking *OK*
6. MikTeX should now automatically execute `texhash` and the local tree is from now on the first to be searched by MikTeX
7. If you want to confirm that the latest version is used, create a document with `\usepackage{tikz}` and add the `\listfiles` command before the `\documentclass` command. The log file will then show a file list with dates

Comment: I looked up the link you gave, but I don't see any "Latest stable build" like the one they have at sourceforge. Is there a way of making sure that I get the latest stable build?

Comment: Note that this is still serving version 2.10, so isn't the latest version any more - it may be late enough for many applications.

Answer (score 24):

## Simple way: via SourceForge

The current CVS version of TikZ/PGF is now [available on sourceforge](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/).

The `.tds.zip` archive should be unpacked in the root directory of a TDS tree (like `~/texmf` for example).

## Complex way: create your own TDS archive from sourceforge source code via CVS

### 1. Get the current version from sourceforge via CVS

```
cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/pgf login
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/pgf co -P pgf
```

- first command request a password: you can type <kbd>Enter</kbd> (to use an empty password).
- after using these two commands, you get a `pgf` subdirectory with latest files.

### 2. Create a script to compile pgfmanual and make the TDS archive

```
#!/bin/sh
# update from sourceforge via CVS
cd pgf; cvs update -d; cd ..
# compile pgfmanual via lualatex
cd pgf/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-luatex/en
LUAINPUTS=".:../../../../..//:" TEXINPUTS=".:../../../../..//:" make
LUAINPUTS=".:../../../../..//:" TEXINPUTS=".:../../../../..//:" make dist
LUAINPUTS=".:../../../../..//:" TEXINPUTS=".:../../../../..//:" make dist
cd ../../../../../..
# create TDS archive
make -f pgf/scripts/pgf/Makefile.pgf_release
cp pgf/doc/generic/pgf/ChangeLog pgf_CVS.ChangeLog
```

Put the above script in a file named `make-distrib-lua.sh` and change file mode bits to allow execution (`chmod a+x make-distrib-lua.sh`).

After these two steps, you have the `make-distrib-lua.sh` script and the `pgf` subdirectory in the same location.

### 3. Make your TDS archive

Launch the script above to compile pgfmanual and make your own TDS archive:

`./make-distrib-lua.sh`

This script:

- updates pgf files with latest version.
- compile the pgfmanual via `lualatex`.
- make the TDS archive
- copy the ChangeLog file

With a good computer, the complete operation takes about fifteen minutes and you get three files:

1. `pgf_CVS.tds.zip` (the TDS archive)
2. `pgf_CVS.pdf` (the pgfmanual)
3. `pgf_CVS.ChangeLog` (the ChangeLog file)

**Important:** At each update, **only the third step must be done** !

Comment: When I try to follow your steps, I get an error message:  ` (../../text-en/pgfmanual-en-tutorial-nodes.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@p@c@s@group #1^^@-\iftikz@handle@active@node 
                                                 \expandafter \def \expandaf...
l.41 ... (w1)                                    {};`

Comment: @A.Ellett This is a CVS version. It is sometimes unstable... Today, I get the same error as you.

Comment: @PaulGaborit That's what I will do. (b.t.w I deleted the ancient comments to not make this place look like reddit)

Comment: I tried the simple way and unpacked "pgf" into my ~/texmf directory.  It seems to be still using the old version of tikz-cd.  What command(s) should I use to update it?  (I'm using texlive)

Comment: @YanKingYin `tikz-cd` is not `TikZ/PGF`. To update, you may copy files from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd in  a new `~/texmf/tex/latex/tikz-cd` folder... Or update your TeXLive installation: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution

Comment: I updated my TexLive but the tikz-cd version is still completely out-dated.  I unzipped the new tikz-cd into my local ~/texfm but I don't know how to get it to be used...

Comment: It seems that once I use TexLive I lost control of manually installing packages, is that true?

Comment: @YanKingYin With TeXLive (as other distribution), you can always install and use manually installed packages...

Comment: OK, so now I have the package unzipped to the local ~/texmf, how can I activate it?  It seems to be still using the old version of tikz-cd that came with texlive.

Comment: Does `mktexlsr` work with TexLive?

Comment: OK I can load the new tikz-cd now, but it's not compatible with the tikz that came with TexLive.

Comment: @YanKingYin So, to update TikZ/PGF, you may apply the recipe from the answer above...

Comment: I gave up the manual route.  I downloaded the newer version of TexLive from tug, made sure the version is 2015, and everything worked straightaway.

Answer (score 11):

There are fairly good installation instruction in the pgf manual, however, there seems to be few small discrepancies between the current (v. 2.10) manual and the reality.  First, the manual mentions tarball (.tgz) file, and the recent builds seem to all be distributed as zip files, second, the recent builds all seem to contain a TDS (TeX Directory Structure) compliant trees (you can tell since the files have names like `pgfCVS2010-09-28_TDS.zip`, which means that a TDS compliant installation should be really easy.

I highly recommend installing the package into either a local or a personal texmf tree.  That way when your package manager (whether it is a part of your operating system or your tex distribution) will not replace your major upgrade a some minor one in the future.

The usual locations of these threes are described in the pgf manual.  The local tree is usually `/usr/local/share/texmf/` on unix based systems (linux, bsd, maybe mac?) and `C:\localtexmf\` on windows.  If you do not have administrator privileges on your system, you will want to use your local tree, usually in `~/texmf/` on unix (I don't know where the location is on windows).

Now to the actual installation: download the zipped file (either current stable release from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/) or a development build from [texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/builds/)).  Make sure the file has `TDS` in the name somewhere, it should be something like `pgf_some_version_info.tds.zip` or `pgfsome_version_info_TDS.zip`. Simply unzip the file into your local or personal TDS tree directory.  Then run `texhash`, which should update the tex file database so TeX can find your new files.

I am making this a community wiki, since there are so many things other people can add or correct (different operating systems, different TeX distributions, ...)

Comment: On a mac the good directory is ~/Library/texmf I think now with TL2010 or MACTEX2010 run texhash is not necessary. When I want for example to try pgf 2.1 CVS, I put the files inside ~/Library/texmf ( I used only generic files and latex files) then If I want to go back at pgf 2.1, I make an archive (.zip) of the pgf  folders and I put the cvs version in the trash. This is enough to compile with pgf 2.1 or pgf 2.1 cvs. It's the same way with 2.0 and 2.1

Answer (score 9):

NOTE: This answer is out of date, as PGF/TikZ is now part of the Debian TeX Live packages, and does not require separate installation.

This answer is for users of PGF and Debian or Ubuntu, or other Debian
derived Linux distributions.

The most recent version of PGF available in Debian and Ubuntu is 2.0,
from 2008. The TeX distribution used by Debian and Ubuntu is Tex Live,
currently Tex Live 2009. It turns out that making a PGF 2.10 package
for Debian is easy, and works with Tex Live 2009. This method should
also work with development versions. Making Debian packages as opposed
to a local installation has obvious advantages, including clean
upgrades and the opportunity for automated installs across large
numbers of machines.

According to the Debian PGF maintainer, he will be packaging 2.10 soon. See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=606128

So, here is a recipe, assuming only a modest amount of knowledge about
Debian packaging.

If you don't want to go through the recipe below, you can download the
PGF binary from the following temporary location. But the recipe below
is easier than it looks, honest.

http://bulldog.duhs.duke.edu/~faheem/debian/pgf_2.10-0_all.deb

1) Download the Debian sources for PGF 2.0. This assumes you have a
line in /etc/apt/sources.list like

> deb-src http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/ squeeze main non-free contrib

Then do

> $ apt-get source pgf

This will download and unpack the pgf source directory

```
$ apt-get source pgf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Need to get 3,770 kB of source archives.
Get:1 http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/ squeeze/main pgf 2.00-1 (dsc) [902 B]
Get:2 http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/ squeeze/main pgf 2.00-1 (tar) [3,759 kB]
Get:3 http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/ squeeze/main pgf 2.00-1 (diff) [10.8 kB]
Fetched 3,770 kB in 22s (170 kB/s)
dpkg-source: info: extracting pgf in pgf-2.00
dpkg-source: info: unpacking pgf_2.00.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: applying pgf_2.00-1.diff.gz
```

2) Then download the PGF 2.10 source to the same directory.

> $ wget -c http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/pgf/version%202.10/pgf_2.10.tds.zip/download -O pgf_2.10.tds.zip

3) Unzip the source

```
$ mkdir pgf-2.10 
$ cp pgf_2.10.tds.zip pgf-2.10 
$ cd pgf-2.10 
$ unzip pgf_2.10.tds.zip 
$ rm pgf_2.10.tds.zip
```

4) Copy the debian directory from pgf-2.00

```
$ cd .. 
$ cp -ar pgf-2.00/debian/ pgf-2.10/
```

At this point it is probably a good idea to put the files under
pgf-2.10/ under version control so you can roll back if you screw
up. I use and recommend mercurial.

> $ cd pgf-2.10/debian/

5) Now some easy changes.

Change 1: This corresponds to a reorganization of the files in
PGF. Just change the following line. You need to use a tab instead of
spaces here.

```
# HG changeset patch
# User Faheem Mitha <faheem@email.unc.edu>
# Date 1298803034 -19800
# Node ID a0b004038f1525f2c4b9826d04624ac086df85ed
# Parent  84bf199052f3b87890ece302867a0ed0eeed73b9
Changes to debian/rules

diff -r 84bf199052f3 -r a0b004038f15 debian/rules
--- a/debian/rules      Sun Feb 27 15:43:12 2011 +0530
+++ b/debian/rules      Sun Feb 27 16:07:14 2011 +0530
@@ -63,7 +63,7 @@
                $(DOCDIR)/pgf
 #      cp -r doc/generic/pgf/version-for-tex4ht/en/*      #              $(DOCDIR)/pgf/html/
-       cp -r context generic latex plain $(TEXMF)/tex
+       cp -r tex/context tex/generic tex/latex tex/plain $(TEXMF)/tex
```

CHANGE 2: Change the compat level. The file debian/compat contains the
number 4. Simply change it to 7.

> pgf-2.10/debian$ echo 7 > compat

will work

```
# HG changeset patch
# User Faheem Mitha <faheem@email.unc.edu>
# Date 1298803274 -19800
# Node ID a3f351d6056adfd81f30cbd3159addb1dba04506
# Parent  302a183d556d05654c4b045ffe028ce6557cc008
Update debian/compat

diff -r 302a183d556d -r a3f351d6056a debian/compat
--- a/debian/compat     Sun Feb 27 16:08:54 2011 +0530
+++ b/debian/compat     Sun Feb 27 16:11:14 2011 +0530
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-4
+7
```

CHANGE 3: Update the changelog.

> pgf-2.10/debian$ dch -i

I used

```
# HG changeset patch
# User Faheem Mitha <faheem@email.unc.edu>
# Date 1298803134 -19800
# Node ID 302a183d556d05654c4b045ffe028ce6557cc008
# Parent  a0b004038f1525f2c4b9826d04624ac086df85ed
Update changelog.

diff -r a0b004038f15 -r 302a183d556d debian/changelog
--- a/debian/changelog  Sun Feb 27 16:07:14 2011 +0530
+++ b/debian/changelog  Sun Feb 27 16:08:54 2011 +0530
@@ -1,3 +1,10 @@
+pgf (2.10-0) unstable; urgency=low
+
+  * Non-maintainer upload.
+  * New upstream version.
+
+ -- Faheem Mitha <faheem@email.unc.edu>  Sun, 27 Feb 2011 16:07:35 +0530
+
 pgf (2.00-1) unstable; urgency=low
```

6) Then

> pgf-2.10/debian$ debuild binary

should build your package and place in the directory above pgf-2.10.

Comment: Why am I building a package?  Does this install tikz-cd?

Comment: @YanKingYin I don't understand your comment, but this answer is out of date. TikZ/PGF is now part of TeX Live and you do not require a special package.

Answer (score 0):

This answer gave the solution for me! https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343324/202358

In short: `apt install texlive-latex-extra`

Comment: This doesn't particularly answer the question which is about how to install a latest/in-development version of TikZ, the Debian/Ubuntu TeX Live is typically several years out of date so this likely won't even give the most recent stable release of TikZ. The general advice in [the currently accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12090/106162) to install/update through your tex distribution largely subsumes this answer.

Comment: The currently accepted answer led me to a total dead end, so after researching the problem for a considerable amount of time and finding such a simple solution which solved the problem for me, I decided to share my experience. :)

Comment: Hmm, I see how the currently accepted answer could be considered lacking, maybe that can be improved. I also appreciate that this solves your question (which is more or less the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016), but that is a distinct question from the one the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

For Tex Live distributions, you can use `tlmgr`:

```
tlmgr install pgf
```

Confirmed working with TinyTex.