# How can I upgrade to pgf 2.10

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, texlive, pgf-2.10

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/ shows that 2 days ago (25 Oct 2010) version 2.10 of PGF (Tikz) is released.

I am currently using texlive 2010. Will pgf 2.10 come in texlive 2010, or do I have to wait a year? If it will be not included, how can I still use pgf 2.10 with texlive 2010?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but maybe useful: [“How to install a current version of TikZ?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The release notice says it's been submitted to CTAN, so I recommend waiting until the update propagates to TeX Live (or MiKTeX for users of that distro) and then using the standard update utilities to get it automatically; e.g., in TeX Live 2010:

```
sudo tlmgr update pgf
```

The turn-around time to for an update to appear in TL is usually fairly small, although I don't see it available quite yet.

Comment: This morning tlmgr updated pgf for me to version 2.10!

Comment: if I am having proxy how I can upgrade this??@will

Answer (score 1):

There are installation instructions in the pgf manual, section 8 for the version you are trying ti install.  You want to install pgf 2.10 into your local or personal `texmf` tree.  It will then override the system version.   You will have two versions if pgf installed, but TeX will use the one in your local or personal tree rather than the one in the system tree.

The location of your local or personal `texmf` tree depends on your operating system.  On linux,  they are usually in `/usr/local/share/texmf` and `~/texmf', respectively.