# Dynamic "expansion" of tikz calendar's cells?

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, calendar

Please, is that possible. Having started with this latex source, i would like to have calendar's cells "expandable" vertically -- please see the picture below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\def\testmsgShort{Short message}
\def\testmsgLong{Long message for testing purposes}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={
            text width=3cm
  }]
\calendar [
    day list downward,
    name=cal,
    dates=2011-01-01 to 2011-01-11
  ]
  if (weekend) [black!25];
  \node [anchor=base west] at (cal-2011-01-03.base east)
          {\textcolor{orange}{\textbf{\testmsgShort}}};
  \node [anchor=base west] at (cal-2011-01-09.base east)
          {\textcolor{orange}{\textbf{\testmsgLong}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: calendar with (long) text labels]

As you can see, long text nodes are not related to days (at least visually). More naturally would be to see a calendar in a form like a table with "day" and "label" columns. Well, i understand that it's hardly possible with a setup like this, because of calendar is already drawn, "printed out", so new nodes can not expand its "cells".

So, my questions is -- is this "cells expansion" possible with tikz/calendar? If yes -- how? Should i look for any other way? Which one, please?

---

**Update**:

Thank you, Jake!

Actually i would like to be possible to "collect" events, like this:

```
\tikzstyle{red events}=[
    execute after day scope=
    {
        \redevent{2011-01-04}{This is a long event text.}
        \redevent{2011-01-07}{Short event!}
    }
]

\tikzstyle{blue events}=[
    execute after day scope=
    {
        \blueevent{2011-01-04}{This is another long event text.}
        \blueevent{2011-01-08}{Short another}
    }
]

% ...
\calendar [
    % ...
    red events,
    blue events
    % ...
```

I am not sure that this is the optimal way to "collect events". Saying "collecting events" i mean that some events may be the same forever (think of birthdays), some others may be movable; i believe it's convenient to separate them and have a possibility to edit-comment-uncomment--etc-etc.

But this does not work with your code (i have overlapping events), and i could not imagine (i have poor tikz imagination so far, sorry), how to make it possible.

One way is, possibly, to define "initial offset" and accumulate it -- but wouldn't it be too expensive to define variables for offsets for whole year?

Is there any other way?

ps. Thank you a lot for your effort, Jake; your answer will be the best one in any case, but i would like to ask for even better solution (if that's possible), anyway .)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here's another attempt: The events are collected in macros that change the new `event` style:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\event[2]{
    \ifdate{equals=#1} {
% In the following, the event nodes are defined
% The \rule in the node text is necessary to match the "text depth=0.5ex" of the date nodes
    \pgftransformxshift{\columnspace}
        \node [anchor= north west,text height=1.5ex,
            name=txt\pgfcalendarsuggestedname,
            text width=3.5cm,event]
        {#2\rule[-0.5ex]{0ex}{0ex}}; 
% Calculate the vertical offset of the southern anchors of the date and event nodes
            \pgfextracty{\extray}{\pgfpointdiff
        {\pgfpointanchor{txt\pgfcalendarsuggestedname}{south} }
        {\pgfpointanchor{\pgfcalendarsuggestedname}{south} }
        }
 Shift by offset
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{txt\pgfcalendarsuggestedname}{south west} }
    \pgftransformxshift{-\columnspace}
    }{}
}

\newcommand\redevents{
    \tikzstyle{event}=[red]
    \event{2011-01-04}{This is a very long event text running over three lines.}
    \event{2011-01-07}{Short event!}
    \event{2011-01-08}{Third of the longish events\ldots}
}
\newcommand\blueevents{
    \tikzstyle{event}=[blue]
        \event{2011-01-04}{This is another long event text.}
        \event{2011-01-08}{Short another}
        \event{2011-01-10}{Single blue event}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\dayyshift{2ex} % Set space between days
\def\columnspace{4pt} % Set extra space between day and event column

\newdimen{\extray} % Define new dimen for calculating vertical offset

\calendar [
    name=cal,
    dates=2011-01-01 to 2011-01-14,
    every day/.style={
    anchor=north east,
    text depth=0.5ex,
    text height=1.5ex,
    text width=.3cm,
    align=right},
    execute after day scope=
    {
    \extray=0pt
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{\pgfcalendarsuggestedname}{north east}}
%
    \redevents
    \blueevents
%
% Draw separator only if day of month is not 1
    \ifdate {day of month=1} {}{\draw [gray] (\pgfcalendarsuggestedname.north west) ++(90:3pt) -- +(0:4cm);}
% Shift coordinate system to next date
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{\pgfcalendarsuggestedname}{base east}}
    \pgftransformyshift{-\extray}
    \pgftransformyshift{-\dayyshift}
    }
]
if (weekend) [gray!75];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Calendar that collects different events]

Comment: Thank you a lot, indeed! Please, could you take a look, i've updated my question. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Well, my tikz misplaces hrules (http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/6037/testhg.png) and claims he doesn't know what's "align" (! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/align' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.) -- but i believe it's my local problem. So, for now it is GREAT, thank you!

Comment: @brownian: You need to update your PGF installation, see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4623/how-can-i-upgrade-to-pgf-2-10)

Comment: I have a question about node alignment. If I wanted to put a red circle around every Wednesday, I would normally do a "every day/.style={anchor=mid}", but this example relies on the "base east" anchor. How could I change this code to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way to do this by just placing two nodes, one for the possibly long text and one for the actual day of the date which is always placed in relation to the left of the text node.

You can add text by using the `feed orange` and `feed blue` keys and giving them a list of events in the format of `<date> / <text>`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  side orange/.initial=, side blue/.initial=,
  day list downward with side text/.style={
    execute before day scope=%
      \ifdate{equals=\pgfcalendarbeginiso}{\pgfcoordinate{cal@previous}{\pgfpointorigin}}{
        \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{cal@previous}{south west}}
        \ifdate{day of month=1}{
          \pgftransformyshift{-(\tikz@lib@cal@month@yshift)}
          \pgfcoordinate{cal@previous}{\pgfpointorigin}}{}},
    every day/.style = {node contents=\tikzdaytext, name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname},
    day code={%
      \node[anchor=north west, outer sep=+0pt, alias=cal@previous,
        name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname-text, append after command={
          node[anchor=base east, at=(\tikzlastnode.base west), every day]},
        every day text];},
    every day text/.style={
      align=left, text width=3cm, outer sep=+0pt, minimum height=\tikz@lib@cal@yshift,
      font=\vphantom{A},
      node contents=%
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/side orange}\tikz@tempa
        \pgfutil@ifxempty\tikz@tempa{}{\color{orange}\tikz@tempa}%
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/side blue}\tikz@tempb
        \pgfutil@ifxempty\tikz@tempb{}{%
          \pgfutil@ifxempty\tikz@tempa{}{\par}\color{blue}\tikz@tempb}},
    feed orange/.style args={##1/##2}{if={(equals=##1)[side orange/.append={##2}]}},
    feed blue/.style args={##1/##2}{if={(equals=##1)[side blue/.append={##2}]}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikz\calendar[day list downward with side text, dates=2011-01-01 to 2011-01-11]
  [feed orange/.list = {2011-01-04 / This is a long event text.,
                        2011-01-07 / Short event!}]
  [feed blue/.list   = {2011-01-04 / This is another long event text.,
                        2011-01-08 / Short another?}];
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]