# Problem with installing current version of TikZ.

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have installed Texlive 2010 on Ubuntu 10.10 from .iso image. now I want to upgrade my pgf. After following [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz) steps, I receive this error:

```
! I can't find file `pgfmathfunctions.code.tex'.
l.16 \input pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
```

I searched that file and found it in pgf's directories. When I copy it beside of my tex file, another error is occurred: the program is unable to find another file; that exists in pgf directories...

**Note:**
I do `sudo texhash` after replacing new directories.

Comment: It seems that tex is not able to find your files.  Where exactly are your pgf directories?  Which exact instructions did you follow? The question you linked to has two answers, one of them is Windows (actually, MikTeX) specific, the other one in my opinion lacks many details, and, again in my opinion, mistakenly advises to install new version in the regular texmf tree rather than a local texmf tree.

Comment: there are in /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf, /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf, and etc. so where should I copy new files?

Comment: ... and what is local texmftree?

Comment: I a typical TeX distribution, all tex and realted (e.g. metafont, I believe that's where the `mf` comes from) files are kept in several directory trees. There is the main texmf tree (on linux `/usr/share/texmf`) which contains all the tex files that were installed by your package manager (that would be `apt-get` or `synaptic` on ubuntu, texlive's own package manager on some other systems).  You should not change anything there manually, since all your changes are going to be overwritten next time the file you change gets automatically updated.

Comment: Continuing previous comment: all user installed file should go either into the local texmf tree (on ubuntu it will be `/usr/local/share/texmf`) or your personal tree (`~/texmf`).

Comment: I am thinking it may even be a problem with your TeXLive installation. Are you sure TeX looks for files in the right place?  Do you have any other TeX system installed (TeXLive 2009 or teTeX, one of those would normally be installed in Ubuntu)?  Which latex executable gets called when you use latex? Where does it search for its files?  And, and I think this is most likely the problem, which texhash executable gets called when you do `sudo texhash`?

Comment: for some reasons my tlmgr does not work. so I have to install everything manually. copying extracted files into `/usr/local/share/texmf` and calling `texhash` didn't help. now the old pgf is there but newly installed one is not loaded, I guess. (because `\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee}` didn't work for me)

Comment: I just have texlive 2010 on my ubuntu 10.10 installed by downloaded image (not from repositories). I'm using XeLaTeX executable. And when I call `texhash` updated directories are ` /usr/local/share/texmf/,
/var/lib/texmf/,
/var/lib/texmf/,
/var/lib/texmf/ `

Comment: what is the error message when you try to run tlmgr?

Comment: @Caramdir: I write it n the comments of below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but the current archive of TeX Live 2010 actually contains pgf/tikz v2.10. So

```
 sudo tlmgr update --all
```

will (amongst others) download tikz v.2.10 and install it.

EDIT: I think I know what is going on: You have both TeX Live 2009 from the Ubuntu archive and TeX Live 2010 installed. For your normal user $PATH is set such that TL2010 is seen, but for root path doesn't point to the TL2010 installation. So whenever you call `sudo texhash` it will actually use the TL2009 texhash, which of course causes problems.

Comment: I don't have a working `tlmgr` :-(

Comment: What happens when you try to run `tlmgr`?  That may be related to your `texhash` problem.

Comment: `sudo tlmgr update --all` gives `sudo: tlmgr: command not found` but bash knows `tlmgr` without `sudo` before it, but it doesn't work (`tlmgr update --all` gives `tlmgr: package repository /media/Documents/Programs/TeX/tex/texlive2010-20100826
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2010/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.`).

Comment: try `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr update --all` or `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self` (depending on which architecture you have installed.

Comment: It's now updating....

Comment: Is my guessing (see the edited answer) correct?

Comment: Hmmm.... I think isn't.

Comment: because `texhash` shows me tl2010 directories.

Comment: I don't think it does.  As you wrote above, it shows `/usr/local/share/texmf/, /var/lib/texmf/, /var/lib/texmf/, /var/lib/texmf/` which are the system TeX directories, so they would belong to the tl2009.