# Tikz \path problem, command not found

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am following tikz tutorial and my code has reached to this point:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations,shadows}  
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}  
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}  
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}  
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}  
\usetikzlibrary{calc}  
\usepackage{verbatim}  

\begin{document}

\tikzset{Yasser grid/.style={help lines,color=blue!50}}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]  
    \clip (-0.1,-0.2) rectangle (1.1, .75);  
    \draw [Yasser grid, step=0.5cm] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);  
    \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);  
    \draw (0,1.5) -- (0,-1.5);  
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);  
    \draw (3mm,0mm) arc (0:30:3mm);  

    \shadedraw[left color=gray,right color=green, draw=green!50!black]  
        (0,0) -- (3mm,0mm) arc (0:30:3mm) -- cycle;  
        \draw [red, very thick] (30:1cm) -- +(0, -0.5);  
        \draw [blue, very thick] (30:1cm) ++(0, -0.5) -- (0,0);  
        \draw [green, very thick] (0,0) -- (30:1cm);   
        \draw [orange, very thick] (1,0) -- (30: 1.1547cm);  
        \path [name path=upward line](1,0) -- (1,1);  
        \path [name path=sloped line](0,0) -- (30: 1.5cm);  
        \draw [name intersections={of=upward line and sloped line, by=x}][very thick , orange] (1,0) -- (x);  

    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

I have seen these posts:

- [How to install a current version of TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz)
- [Weird tikz/pgfkeys error while trying example from the tikz manual.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/weird-tikz-pgfkeys-error-while-trying-example-from-the-tikz-manual)

I am using TexShop (MacOS) and I followed the instruction in the first post above. Before updating the tikz and after updating it, I am receiving the same error which is similar to the second post above:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/name path' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

If I comment out the \path command every thing is fine. Am I still not using the latest version of tikz? But I have downloaded the latest version and installed it accordingly. Is there any manual on how to completely remove the tikz and install it in texmf-local instead?

Comment: This is the exact place I got stuck as well: nowhere, up to this point in the tutorial, do they mention the command `usetikzlibrary`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to load the `intersections` library:

```
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
```

See *13.3.2 Intersections of Arbitrary Paths* in the TikZ 2.10 manual, which explains also `name path=...` and `name intersections=...`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I have added every thing but that one. There is no comment on tutorial on that.

Comment: There is a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/385/) asking for these instructions to be included in the tutorial