# Curved text (on multiple lines) within curved arrow using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I have a curved arrow and want to put text inside of it (having the same curve as the arrow, of course). If the text is longer than the arrow, the text should be put on multiple lines (optimally with the arrow automatically getting thicker appropriately). See figure below.

(How) can I do this?

[image]

---

Update:

I now use

```
  \coordinate (specRoot) at (-10,0);
  \coordinate (testTreeRoot) at (0,0);
  \draw[->, >=latex, blue!20!white, line width=15pt, bend left]
  (specRoot) to (testTreeRoot);
  \path [decorate,decoration={text along path, text={traverse part of
      the STS and heuristically choose the best test tree}}]
     [out=30] (specRoot) to [in=130] (testTreeRoot);
```

But how can I combine the decorated text along the path and the actual arrow?

How can I do a carriage return, i.e. decorate two lines of text along a single path?

---

Update:

And now I use the following, in the file `lazyOTFoverviewSmall.tex`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.2cm, semithick, mypostaction/.style 2 args={ 
        decoration={
            text align={
                left indent=#1},
                text along path,
                text={#2}
             },
         decorate
         }
  ]

  \begin{scope}[shift={(-10cm,0cm)}]
      \node[state] (specq0) {$q_0$};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
      \node[state] (q0) {$q_0$};
  \end{scope}

  \coordinate (specRoot) at (-10,0);
  \coordinate (testTreeRoot) at (0,0);

  \draw[-latex, blue!20!white, line width=5ex, bend left]
  (specRoot) ++(1cm,1cm)
  to (testTreeRoot) ++(-1cm,1cm);
  \path [postaction={mypostaction={1cm}{traverse part of the STS}},
postaction={mypostaction={1cm}{and heuristically choose the best test
    tree}, /pgf/decoration/raise=-3mm}]
     [out=30] (specRoot) ++(1cm,1cm) to [in=130] (testTreeRoot) ++(-1cm,1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and in `master.tex` I have:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shapes} %pictures
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

....

\begin{document}

...

\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \centering
  \scalebox{.7}{\input{gfx/MBT/lazyOTFoverviewSmall.tex}}
  \caption{Overview of Lazy On-the-fly MBT}\label{fig:lazyOTFoverview}
\end{figure}

....
```

Comment: I have tried http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58510/inserting-text-inside-an-arrow-in-tikz, but the text will not be curved in those cases :(

Comment: You can use Torbjørn's answer with a text decoration instead of a node.

Comment: There's some offset parameter for the `text along path` decoration. You could probably shift the first half of the text up, and the second half down via a `postaction`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TikZ is trying hard but text decorations are not really perfect as the text is decomposed into individual letters and spaces then boxed and rotated. So in general it needs further tweaks to make it look good. The main obstacle is the large arrowhead that changes the bending of the path to fit the arrowhead so the path needs to be adjusted manually. Here is a quick demo but I would recommend different paths for each line to be placed.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mypostaction/.style 2 args={
                         decoration={
                              text align={
                                    left indent=#1},
                                    text along path, 
                                    text={#2}
                                    },
                           decorate
                        }
                    ]
  \coordinate (specRoot) at (-10,0);
  \coordinate (testTreeRoot) at (0,0);
  \draw[-latex, blue!20!white, line width=5ex]  (specRoot) to[in=135,out=45] (testTreeRoot);

  \path [postaction={mypostaction={1cm}{traverse part of the STS}},
         postaction={mypostaction={1cm}{and heuristically choose the best test tree},
         /pgf/decoration/raise=-3mm}]
    (specRoot) to [in=120,out=45] (testTreeRoot);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great. Unfortunately, I get the pdflatex error `ERROR: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/text align' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` I did use `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}` and he seems to find that library, since that line doesn't give errors.

Comment: @DaveBallakauser750378 Can you include your own MWE by editing your question? This is working without any problems on my computer. I'm using TikZ version 2.10.

Comment: MWE = Minimal Working Environment? I have included an SFE (small failing environment), hope my bug jumps right into your eye ;)

Comment: @DaveBallakauser750378 Your code also works (though the result is a little skewed). You can put `\listfiles` command somewhere in your preamble and check the log file for the TikZ.

Comment: My log file says: Package: pgf 2008/01/15 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.12). Going to check the pgfkeys package documentation now...

Comment: Even if I use all libraries as in http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2009-04/msg00349.html, I still get the error message from above.

Comment: I guess my problem's related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/weird-tikz-pgfkeys-error-while-trying-example-from-the-tikz-manual, though the solution there doesn't help either.

Comment: Could you give me the value of the key `text align`? I can then use `\pgfkeys{/my search path/.unknown/.code=
{ \let\searchname=\pgfkeyscurrentname \pgfkeysalso{...`

Comment: @DaveBallakauser750378 Your TikZ is outdated. You need to upgrade to v2.10.

Answer (score 2):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

The text in the arrow is given by the third variable. This text is denoted by `\WCvarC` and used in the key `arc data`. Here, `\\` can be used to split the text over multiple lines.

This text is centered in the arc with the key `arc data pos=0.5`.

The arrow is obtained with the key `slices end arrow={1}{-1}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  arc data=\WCvarC,
  arc data angle shift=2,
  arc data expand=f,
  arc data pos=0.5,
  data=,
  radius={4}{5},
  slices end arrow={1}{-1},
  slices style={\WCvarB,draw=black,very thick},
  start half,
  total angle=60
]{1/blue!20/text that is curved and\\can be on multiple lines}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```