# Curved text within a curved arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to get the text that I place inside a curved arrow to curve with the arrow. I have the following code that generates that given picture, but I wonder how I can get the text to curve with the arrow. I have found a solution proposal [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75432/curved-text-on-multiple-lines-within-curved-arrow-using-tikz), but I could not adapt it to my case. In particular, I would really like to get the definition of vecArrow to be modified to do what I want (ideally with the text as an argument). Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[table,xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,positioning,decorations.text,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Curved Arrow}
 \tikzset{
vecArrow/.style={
  line width=3ex,
  decoration={markings,mark=at position
   1 with {\arrow[scale=2, blue!20!white]{triangle 60}}},
    blue!20!white,
  shorten >= 32pt,
  line width=4pt,
  preaction = {decorate},
  postaction = {draw=blue!20!white,line width=3ex, shorten >= 30pt}
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=2in, minimum height=1in] (box1) {};
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=2in, minimum height=1.5in,below right=of box1] (box2) {};
\draw[vecArrow]  (box1.east) to[in=135,out=45] node[black,rotate=-47,anchor=west,xshift=-6mm]{\scriptsize Subgraph Match} (box2.north);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `decorations.text`. If you don't use a decoration to draw the arrow (but just make the arrow an arrow), then you can use the `text along path` decoration straightforwardly, I think.

Comment: Thanks much. However, as you can see from the code, I am unfortunately using decorations to draw the arrow. If I put text along path inside the decorations (in vecArrow definition) then it doesn't put an arrow head.

Comment: Why can't you draw the arrow head not as a decoration?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it:

```
\documentclass[table,xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,positioning,decorations.text}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    vecArrow/.style={
      draw, line width=3ex, blue!20!white, -{Triangle[bend, angle=60:1pt 2]}, shorten >=6pt, postaction=decorate, decoration={text along path, text color=black, text align=center, text={|\scriptsize|#1 ||}}
    }
  }
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Curved Arrow}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=2in, minimum height=1in] (box1) {};
      \node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=2in, minimum height=1.5in,below right=of box1] (box2) {};
      \path [vecArrow=Subgraph Match] (box1.east) to[in=135,out=45] (box2.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Text on curved arrow]

Comment: @ozsu Glad it helped. Don't forget that the local way of saying 'thanks' is to vote an answer up and/or, after a couple of days, to accept the most helpful of the answers you get. (You probably wouldn't want to accept anything at this point, though, as it is too soon.)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to vote up -- I just did.

Comment: @ozsu No problem. It always feels wrong to ask but usually if somebody says something would work great, they generally *mean* to do the equivalent of up-voting even if the answer is not ideal. I hope somebody will answer your question by showing how to *combine* the decorations as that would be really useful but I've no idea how to do it or even if it can be done.