# How do I arrange my 3 fancy arrows with tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

I have 3 fancy arrows to use for an illustration. One curved arrow with `As the block size increase` inscribed, the second pointing up with `VARIANCE` text inscribed and the third with`BIAS` text inscribed.

I can only do this in `articleclass` it does not run in `beamerclass` where I want it.

I got the text code from [Curved text (on multiple lines) within curved arrow using tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75432/curved-text-on-multiple-lines-within-curved-arrow-using-tikz) and [Fancy arrows with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84143/fancy-arrows-with-tikz) though I modified them.

**Here is my MWE**

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shapes.arrows,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{xparse}


\tikzfading[name=arrowfading, top color=transparent!0, bottom color=transparent!95]
\tikzset{arrowfill/.style={#1,general shadow={fill=black, shadow yshift=-0.8ex, path fading=arrowfading}}}
\tikzset{arrowstyle/.style n args={3}{draw=#2,arrowfill={#3}, single arrow,minimum height=#1, single arrow,
    single arrow head extend=.3cm,}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tikzfancyarrow}{O{2cm} O{FireBrick} O{top color=OrangeRed!20, bottom color=Red} m}{
\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\node [arrowstyle={#1}{#2}{#3}] {#4};
}



\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[mypostaction/.style 2 args={
decoration={
    text align={
        left indent=#1},
    text along path, 
    text={#2}
},
decorate
}
]
\coordinate (specRoot) at (-10,0);
\coordinate (testTreeRoot) at (0,0);
\draw[-latex, blue!20!white, line width=5ex]  (specRoot) to[in=135,out=45] (testTreeRoot);


\path [postaction={mypostaction={1cm}{As block length increases}},postaction={mypostaction={1cm}
    /pgf/decoration/raise=-3mm}] (specRoot) to [in=135,out=45] (testTreeRoot);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzfancyarrow[1.5cm][DarkBlue][top color= PaleTurquoise,bottom color=DeepSkyBlue,shape border rotate=90]{VARIANCE}
\tikzfancyarrow[1.5cm][DarkBlue][top color= DeepSkyBlue,bottom color=PaleTurquoise,shape border rotate=270]{BIAS}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Here is what I want**

I want the curved fancy arrow to be placed side-by-side, (it being at the left of the rest 2 arrows) with the 2 short arrows and to point in an increasing manner (not downward as it is in my text code).

I want the arrow with inscribed `VARIANCE` to be directly on top of the arrow with `BIAS` inscribed and the 2 short arrows (with moderate vertical space) to be the same size regardless of the text-lengths.

I want the arrows arranged in `beamerclass` with `\usetheme{Madrid}`

[image]

Comment: Since `beamer` produces a pdf with small paper size, I think that your problem is related with spaces and lengths you are using.

Comment: If you add `fragile` to the options of the frame your code runs fine with `beamer`. But your are nesting `tikzpicture`s.

Comment: @Sigur it runs but with errow

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I will not mind putting every `tikzpicture s` into one

Comment: I put `\vspace{}` in between the 2 short arrows yet no space is noticed

Comment: I have added a sketch on the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally not a good idea to nest `tikzpicture`s . Also in your current setting you need to add `fragile` to the `frame` options because the styles have parameters. I basically had to completely rewrite the code to get

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,shadows.blur,positioning,arrows.meta,
bending,decorations.text,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newbox\eqnodebox
\tikzset{equal size/.style={execute at begin
    node={\setbox\eqnodebox=\hbox\bgroup},
    execute at end node={\egroup\eqmakebox[#1][c]{\copy\eqnodebox}}},
    equal size/.default=A,}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{Some arrows}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mypostaction/.style n args=3{
   decoration={
       text align={
           left indent=#1},
       text along path, 
       text={#2},#3
   },
   decorate
   },my arrow/.style={draw=DarkBlue,single arrow,single arrow head extend=.3cm,top color=PaleTurquoise,bottom
   color=DeepSkyBlue,shape border rotate=90,blur shadow,minimum height=2cm}
   ]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=Meow]
  \node[my arrow,equal size=A](VAR){VARIANCE};
  \node[my arrow,equal size=A,below=1ex of VAR,shape border rotate=-180]{BIAS};
 \end{scope}
 \draw[thick,decoration=brace,decorate] (Meow.south west) -- (Meow.north west)
  coordinate[midway,xshift=-1em] (aux);
 \draw[-{Latex[bend,length=5em]}, blue!20!white, line width=5ex,
 postaction={mypostaction={1em}{As block length increases}{raise=-0.7ex}}] 
  (aux)++ (-5,-1)  to[bend right]  (aux);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are *many* things that got changed.

Comment: great answer, can you make arrow `VARIANCE` to face up and  arrow `BIASE` to face down

Comment: can you also make the curved arrow to curve from down to up pointing to the direction you rightly put it now, just to show that `the block size is increasing?

Comment: @DanielJames I do not understand the second comment at all.

Comment: On my first comment, I want the arrow with `VARIANCE` to be up and the mouth of it to face up, while the arrow with `BIAS` to be under and it mouth to face down. That is for my fist comment.

Comment: @DanielJames All you need to do is to change the `shape border rotate` and `below` keys. You wrote "VARIANCE to face up and arrow BIASE to face down" and this is what it looks like now.

Comment: @DanielJames You can just add a sketch to your question if you have difficulties changing the keys. I really tried to interpret what you wrote, and posted the answer accordingly.

Comment: I have added a sketch

Comment: @DanielJames Updated. Will be offline now.