# TikZ Library Not Found

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, installing

I am new to TikZ and reading through the manual working out the first example which happens to use the *intersections* library. When I try

```
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
```

LaTex spits out the following error:

> ./tikz.tex:5:I can't find file `tikzlibraryintersections.code.tex'

Does anyone know how I can somehow get the library and where I should put it?

Comment: The `intersections` library is part of TikZ, you don't need to install it separately.  If TikZ cannot find it, it could mean that your TikZ package is incorrectly installed.

Comment: Jan - I just tried reinstalling _texlive-pictures_ package from synaptic and also tried
    `sudo aptitude install pgf`
as suggested in the manual. Neither solved the problem.

Comment: Are you using TeXLive 2009 or 2010? I believe TeXLive 2009 does not have the version of TikZ that includes the intersections library.

Comment: Synaptic has 2009-7 as the latest version, which is what I have installed.

Comment: The 2009 version of texlive is outdated. It is a pain that it ships with e.g. ubuntu. You can either fully update to texlive 2010 or just update the tikz package manually

Comment: @Martin - can you recommend how I install TeXLive 2010? I read here that you cannot "update" due to Ubuntu doing something and also that Ubuntu strips TeXLive 2009 of tlmgr. Yet when I look up how to install TeXLive 2010, sites mention using tlmgr.

Comment: @Hanmyo I installed texlive 2010 in full on my ubuntu 10.10 without any problems. You are right that there is no update from 2009 to 2010. A problem you might run into if you use kile as an editor is that is for some weird reason connected to texlive 2009. I ended up building kile from source. If it is just tikz you are after, the manual package update is easier and for sure quicker

Comment: @Hanmyo: You need to manually install TeX Live 2010. This isn't hard; see [the TeX Live website](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). If you need any help with that, please ask a separate question (either here or on askubuntu.com).

Comment: @Martin or Jake: Could you please add your comment (that one needs v2.10 of TikZ) as an answer, so that it can get accepted. Installing TeX Live manually on Ubuntu should be a separate question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `intersections` library is not included in pgf 2.0, which is the version that ships with TeXLive 2009 (which is the version of TeXLive that ships with Ubuntu up to version 10.10). As Martin suggested in the comments to the question, you can either install TeXLive 2010 [directly from the website](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html), or just update pgf to a recent version (2.10 at time of writing) as [described in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz/5702#5702).

Comment: I am accepting this answer.

What I had to do, because I like using Kile as my LaTeX editor, is:
 - Uninstall Kile
 - Uninstall all signs of TeXLive in synaptic
 - Install TeXLive 2010 [link](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)
 - Reinstall Kile from source [link](http://kile.sourceforge.net/download.php)
 - Make it so I can run kile easily from the command line...
    alias kile='KDEDIRS=$HOME/kile-install:$KDEDIRS $HOME/kile-install/bin/kile'

I also tried a couple of other things like changing paths and folder names in the process, but I think those didn't affect it much.