# How is TikZ on Windows different with TiKZ on Linux?

Tags: packages, installing

This code snippet compiles fine on Windows 7. However, when I ran it on Linux, the compiler complained that it couldn't find the key `/tikz/align`. Obviously, get rid of the option `align=flush center` solved the compiler errors, but the consequence was I don't get my expected display. Am I missing some other packages here? or there are several differences between TeXLive and MikTeX?

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{polynomial}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mdwtab}


\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.footprints}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=3]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%define new colors
\definecolor{dark-red}{rgb}{0.4,0.15,0.15}
\definecolor{dark-blue}{rgb}{0.15,0.15,0.4}
\definecolor{medium-blue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}

%set up color for table of contents
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks, linkcolor={medium-blue},
    citecolor={dark-blue}, urlcolor={medium-blue}
}

\usepackage{tocloft}

%preven linebreak between subsection header and its content
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{3pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{3pt}{}
%title
\title{\textbf{Solution for Chapter 1}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
        \node[state,initial]    (q_1)                           {$q_1$}; 
        \node[state,accepting]  (q_2)   [right=of q_1]          {$q_2$}; 
        \node[state]            (q_3)   [below right=of q_1]    {$q_3$}; 

        \path[->]
        (q_1) edge  [bend left]     node {a}            (q_2)
        (q_1) edge  [loop above]    node {b}            (q_1)
        (q_2) edge  [bend left]     node {a,b}          (q_3)
        (q_3) edge  [bend left]     node {a}            (q_2)
        (q_3) edge  [bend left]     node {b}            (q_1);

        \node [below=1cm, align=flush center,text width=8cm] at (q_3)
        {
            $M_1$
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you checked that your TikZ versions are identical on both systems? You can check your version by inserting `\pgfversion` after `\begin{document}`; the version will then be printed in your document. I suspect your Linux version is older than 2.1, and should really be updated.

Comment: @Jake: You're right. On my Linux system, it is 2.00. I do need an update. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might find this question useful on getting the most recent version of TikZ/PGF: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2044/86

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to obtain an up-to-date version of both systems ([TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) and [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/)) would be via the respective update managers ([tlmgr](http://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html) and [mpm](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html)). However, in general, this is not the case.

The most recent download of TeX Live is **2011** (dated July 20, 2011), while the most recent version of MiKTeX is **2.9** (dated October 2010). If these versions are downloaded as-is, they would have different versions of the packages, possibly leading to different compatibility issues.

The best way to assess the differences between an installation would be to check your .log file, which should output some version information for each package. That way you'll see which version has the most up-to-date (and likely, more compatible) packages.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So should I update TikZ itself rather than the whole TeXLive? and what's the easiest way to update TeXLive?

Comment: The easiest, and possibly quickest, way is to only update what you need via `tlmgr [pkg]`. The [tlmgr documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#update__option______pkg____) gives all the options needed to update *single packages* (by specifying the package, say `pgf`) to *everything* (by specifying the option `-all`).

Comment: I tried `tlmgr` but seemed like this command does not come with TeXlive2009. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04. I think I have to manually re-install TeXLive again.

Comment: The version of TeXlive found in Ubuntu's repositories does not have `tlmgr`. To get that, you have to install TL with the installer found on the TL website.