# Best way to make circuit diagrams for LaTeX?

Tags: circuitikz

I'm using PCTex (WinXP) and looking for the best way to make circuit diagrams for LaTeX.  Something that will allow me to include many arrows, comments and equations around the schematic. The objective is to give step by step instructions on how to solve a problem (like a textbook).  I don't mind a learning curve as long as it will look professional at the end.

Circuit_macros looked appealing but I was not sure how to install it for PCTex.

Comment: I think [circuitikz](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: TikZ also has a library for drawing circuits, which I believe is based on `circuitikz`.

Comment: For circuitikz examples, try searching on this site. There's also a neat diagram [on TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/circuitikz/).

Comment: Echoing @TorbjørnT., you can find it an interesting read of [the pgf manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) starting from page 290.

Answer (score 11):

I was in the same search several weeks earlier, only on the Mac platform.  I finally settled down with the circtuitikz, and found it intuitive to work with.

I abandoned previous choice Circuit_Macro simply because CircuitTiKz **suit my workflow**, that means I don't want to have too much compile work.

My current workflow look likes this, although on *Mac system*, but I would like to see alternatives on other systems, and just share with you my personal experience on drawing circuit diagrams, yes, for illustrating students how to solve them.

1. Write codes in LaTexit and see previews (no compile like Circuit Macro), can see the result and modify quick! That saves time a lot!
2. Drag the preview as PDF to OmniGraffle (A paid program like Visio, The OmniGraffle file is like a library for my circuits 4)
3. When Ineed to put it to Latex, I double click the circuit in OmniGraffle
   and copy the codes. (The equation are linked with OmniGraffle, such
   that the codes generating the circuits are preserved).  That's very
   handy!
4. When I need to put it to slides, I copy it as PDF to
   keynotes or powerpoints.

For me, I think it works well.  The screen capture shows an example of double clicking the linked file to bring back the codes and the preview (the embedded image itself is a pdf generated by LatexIt and dragged to the OmniGraffle canvas)

[image: An screen capture of the linked CircuiTiKz in work]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Tip: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I just modified the post and hopefully it can get through!

Answer (score 6):

PStricks library [pst-circ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-circ) is a very powerful package.  You may want to consider it.

Comment: PCTeX 5 (which I'm using) has pst-circ as one of the optional packages to install. I installed it today and have started doing some basic work. Thank you Boris.

I'm still interested on how to install the circuitikz package on PCTeX 5...

Comment: You should be able to adapt the methods in [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz) for installing TikZ on PCTeX, but you won't find a great deal of support for PCTeX outside of their own forums. Once TikZ is installed, installing circitikz should be straightforward.

Comment: In pst-circ, does anyone know how to rotate the op-amp by 90 degrees?

Comment: Just place the nodes vertically - see page 40 of the manual for an example.

Comment: I'm referring to the 3 terminal op-amps.