# CircuiTikZ code generator with OmniGraffle

Tags: tikz-styles, circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib, circuits, latexit

I just read a thread on here about generating CircuiTikz code with OmniGraffle. I downloaded OmniGraffle and followed the instructions, but was not able to generate the tex-code. My question is: Can someone with OmniGraffle knowledge elaborate the instructions for me? Do I need to use another application to generate the code? And do I need a specific stencils package?

[Best way to make circuit diagrams for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39655/best-way-to-make-circuit-diagrams-for-latex)

Since I don't have enough reputation, I was not allowed to comment on that thread, so that's why I'm making my own.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you at least explain the steps you made and what is going wrong?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, my bad. In step 3 when I double click my circuit nothing happens.