# How can I update TikZ/PGF?

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, scripts, updating

I am searching a script that will do the following.

1. Removing all old PGF/TikZ files in my local texmf tree
2. Installation of all new PGF/TikZ in my local texmf tree of the csv repository:
   [PGF and TikZ -- Graphic systems for TeX --cvs](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=cvs&group_id=142562)
3. Creating the new user manual based on the new files (The csv version provides a `Makefile`)

I have no favourite language.

The best way would be to have script for the platforms Unix / Mac / Windows -- something like `biber`, whereby I use Unix.

I ask this question here because it's mostly PGF/TikZ related.

Comment: It's PGF not pgf. Initialisms are written capitalized. For the same reason it's "a PDF file", not "a pdf file", which technically uses it as an adjective.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Edited.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I am sure I am not the first person who wants to ask this question. ;-)

Comment: Another good question would be: Why is CVS still used for PGF/TikZ? It got outdated by Subversion years ago. Also, using Mercurial or Git would be a good idea.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The problem is that from time to time the compilation of the documentation won't work out of the cvs box. You can try the `tlcontrib` repo if you work with `texlive` (note that I cannot update the `tlcontrib` package for several month due to an unidentified bug, see http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/tlcontrib/2012-February/000212.html

Comment: @cjorssen: Of course I use the tlcontrip repository ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install a current version of TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a script but the method I use with OS X it's possible with Linux

I put the version CVS in my home.
You have a PGF folder

```
 inside /tex/generic          
 inside /tex/latex  
 inside /tex/context 
 inside /tex/plain.
```

Personally I use only `generic` and `latex`.

You can get without CVS the files here [sourceforge](http://pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pgf/pgf/) and you click on Download GNU tarball. You get pgf-pgf.tar.gz, you decompress and you install manually the folders.

To remove, it's possible to remove the folders "pgf" manually. Personally I compress (`.zip`) the folders and then I remove the uncompressed folders. If I have a problem with the new version, I decompress the archives (`.zip`)

For the manual with the CVS version :

1. I get the sources sources via CVS (in the directory
   ~/pgf). I proceed like this :

   ```
   cd ~
   cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/pgf co -P pgf
   ```
2. then for the `pgfmanual` with `pdftex`

   ```
   cd ~/pgf/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-pdftex/en
   ```
3. Create the folder 'plots' if this folder doesn't exist.

   ```
   mkdir plots
   ```
4. You compile a first time:

   ```
   TEXINPUTS=".:~/pgf//:" make
   ```
5. then you compile several times with :

   ```
   TEXINPUTS=".:~/pgf//:" make dist
   ```

   (You need to see if the links are fine. 
   makefile uses the good texmf.cnf.)
   The link colors has been disabled by one of the PGF team (probably a matter of taste): you need to write `colorlinks=true` in the next file `pgfmanual-en-main.tex`:
   remark from Christian Feuersänger

   ```
   \usepackage{hyperref}
     \hypersetup{%
     colorlinks=false, % use true to enable colors below:
     linkcolor=blue,%red,
     filecolor=blue,%magenta,
     pagecolor=blue,%red,
     urlcolor=blue,%cyan,
     citecolor=blue,
     pdfborder=0 0 0,
   }
   ```
6. Now you can create `pgfmathtestsuite.pdf` via :

   ```
   cd ~/pgf/generic/pgf/testsuite/mathtest
   pdflatex pgfmathtestsuite.tex
   ```
7. Finally you can create an archive TDS via :

   ```
   cd ~; make -f pgf/scripts/pgf/Makefile.pgf_release
   ```

   You get three files :

   ```
   ~/pgf_2.10-CVS.ChangeLog
   ~/pgf_2.10-CVS.pdf
   ~/pgf_2.10-CVS.tds.zip
   ```

### Remark 1

With this method you don't have the part about the graphs. To get this section you need to use `LuaLaTeX`, but sometimes there are several  problems. The last time, (15 days) It was not possible to get the entire manual. I get a part with `pdflatex` and another part with `LuaLaTeX`.
You need to inspect the file `pgfmanual-en-main.tex` to see what you need to make.

### Remark 2

I put on my site the version 25-04-2012 files + `pgfmanual`

[altermundus.com](http://altermundus.com/pages/builds/index.html)

Comment: Very kind Alain Matthes the last site altermundus.com it is corrupt. Can you improved it, please? Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to write a shell script which does the job. However to use this script you have to install CVS.

Test the file by your own risk.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# small script to download // install the cvs version of pgf
# I hereby relicense under the GPL (version 3 or later).
# Author: Marco Daniel
# Year: 2012

################################################################
# Declare variables
################################################################
## Name settings
TEMPFOLDER=temppgftempinstall
TEMPDIR=$HOME/Desktop
## Color settings
RED=$(tput setaf 1) #  red
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2) #  blue
BLUE=$(tput setaf 4) #  blue
WHITE=$(tput setaf 7)
## Flag settings
DOCUMENTATION=false
COLORLINKS=false
HELP=false
QUIET=false
REMOVE=false


################################################################
# Options
################################################################
# Loop until we run out of arguments.
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
do
        case "$1" in
        -d | --documenation )
                shift
                DOCUMENTATION=true
                ;;
        -c | --colorlinks )
                shift
                COLORLINKS=true
                DOCUMENTATION=true
                ;;
        -h | --help )
                shift
                HELP=true
                ;;
        -q | --quite )
                shift
                QUIET=true
                ;;
        -r | --remove )
                shift
                REMOVE=true
                ;;
        *)
                echo "Unknown argument '$1'" >&2
                ;;
        esac
        # Delete $1 argument, set $1=$2, $2=$3, ...
        shift
done


################################################################
# Help
################################################################
if [ "$HELP" == "false" ] 
then
 :
else
  echo -e "\n${BLUE}Script to install TikZ/PGF to local texmf folder$WHITE"
  echo -e "${BLUE}Script by Marco Daniel$WHITE"
  echo -e "\n${GREEN}Option\t\tExplanation"
  echo -e "--------------------------------------------------"
  echo -e "${GREEN}-d\t\tcreate documenation"
  echo -e "${GREEN}-c\t\tuse colorlinks in documenation"
  echo -e "${GREEN}-h\t\tprint help"
  echo -e "${GREEN}-q\t\tquiet compilation"
  echo -e "${GREEN}-r\t\tremove temp folder"
  echo -e "--------------------------------------------------"
  echo -e "\n${RED}Note:\t\tThe compilation of the manual"
  echo -e "\t\ttake some time${WHITE}"
  exit 0
fi


################################################################
# Starting script
################################################################
echo -e "${BLUE}Update pgf in texmflocal$WHITE\n"

################################################################
# create temp folder and cvs-download
################################################################
## create new folder in $HOME to download the files
cd $TEMPDIR                          # go to temp dir
rm -r -f $TEMPFOLDER                 # remove older file (if exits)
mkdir $TEMPDIR/$TEMPFOLDER && cd $_  # create new folder and go to

## CVS-Settings
## login to cvs-server of pgf
echo -e "${GREEN}Password -- press return $RED"
 cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/pgf login
## download developing branch
echo -e "\n${GREEN}Download pgf in $TEMPFOLDER"
 cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/pgf -Q checkout -P pgf 
## remove unnecessary folders CVS
echo -e "\n${RED}remove unnecessary folders CVS"
 find * -name CVS  | xargs rm -r -f
echo -e "${GREEN}Done"




################################################################
# Provide TDS-Structure of the downloaded files
################################################################
# provide TDS-Structure
echo -e "\n${RED}create TDS structure"
cd $TEMPDIR/$TEMPFOLDER/pgf
mkdir tex
FOLDERLIST=(context generic incoming latex plain)
for i in "${FOLDERLIST[@]}"
do
   cp -a $i tex
   rm -r -f $i
done
echo -e "${GREEN}Done"


################################################################
# Go to TEXMFHOME
################################################################

echo -e "\n${RED}Your local texmf path is"
PATHTEXHOME=$(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME)
echo $GREEN$PATHTEXHOME$WHITE
## test if TEXMFHOME exists
if [ -d "$PATHTEXHOME" ]
then
 :
else
  echo -e "${RED}$PATHTEXHOME directory doesn't exist!"
  echo -e "create"
  mkdir $PATHTEXHOME
fi
cd $PATHTEXHOME


################################################################
# Remove older versions and copy the new one
################################################################
## removing
echo -e "${RED}remove older version of pgf in texmf local"
find * -name pgf  | xargs rm -r -f
echo -e "${GREEN}Done"

## install files in local texmftree
echo -e "\n${RED}Install to local texmf tree"
echo -e "${RED}Install new files"
cd $TEMPDIR/$TEMPFOLDER/pgf
cp -a tex $PATHTEXHOME
cp -a doc $PATHTEXHOME
echo -e "${GREEN}Done"



################################################################
# Documenation
################################################################

if [ "$DOCUMENTATION" == "false" ] 
then
  echo -e "\n${GREEN}Create no documenation$WHITE"
else
  echo -e "\n${RED}Create documenation -- this take a while$WHITE"
  if [ "$COLORLINKS" == "true" ] 
  then
   echo -e "\n${RED}Using colorlinks option -- replace command$WHITE"
   cd $TEMPDIR/$TEMPFOLDER/pgf/doc/generic/pgf/text-en
    sed -rie "s/(colorlinks=false)/colorlinks=true/" pgfmanual-en-main.tex
  fi
  cd $TEMPDIR/$TEMPFOLDER/pgf/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-pdftex/en
  mkdir plots
  TEXINPUTS=".:~/pgf//:" make
  TEXINPUTS=".:~/pgf//:" make dist
  TEXINPUTS=".:~/pgf//:" make dist
  TEXINPUTS=".:~/pgf//:" make dist
  cp pgfmanual.pdf $PATHTEXHOME/doc/generic/pgf/
  echo -e "\n${GREEN}DONE"
fi

################################################################
# Remove temp folder
################################################################
if [ "$REMOVE" == "true" ] 
then
  cd $TEMPDIR                          # go to temp dir
  rm -r -f $TEMPFOLDER                 # remove older file (if exits)
fi

echo -e "\n${BLUE}COMPLETE ${WHITE}"

################################################################
# End
################################################################
exit 0
################################################################
# End
################################################################
```