# How to update pgf 2.0 to 2.1?

Tags: tikz-pgf, ubuntu, updating

I have installed TikZ/PGF using Synaptic Package Manager. Still it contains version 2.0. Now How do I update it?

Comment: the synaptic package manager contains a very out of date distribution- it's best not to use it! see [how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 (and I think 11.10) seems to contain PGF 2.10 (on top of TL2009).

Comment: You can try to download a newer .deb from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pgf. (There are also untrusted .debs for Lucid and Maverick at https://launchpad.net/~tukss/+archive/ppa/+packages). I don't know whether that will work as expected. In general I'd recommend installing TeX Live directly (see cmhughes' link).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56406/how-can-i-update-tikz-pgf

Answer (score 1):

[Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/) has a `.tds.zip` file, which means it is a snap to install in a vanilla Ubuntu TeX Live (2009) environment. Download the file; move it to the base of your TeX tree (for me that is `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/`); unzip the `.tds.zip` file; run `sudo texhash`; and you're done.

Of course, to manipulate files outside of your 'home' directory, you probably need to use `sudo`.

**Edit:** In fact, as @Caramdir pointed out, Ubuntu 11.10 (and presumably 12.04) have PGF 2.10 installed independently of whatever version shipped with TeX Live 2009, which is the latest version except for those who like to live on the bleeding edge (if a `CVS` version can still be called the bleeding edge!).