# how to install Tikz and PGF on WinEdt6.0

Tags: tikz-pgf, winedt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)

Now I want to use Tikz and PGF， and I referred this instruction [How to install a current version of TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz)

However, I don't know where the settings of MikTeX on WinEdit?

Comment: One of the answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/14100) will show you how to update your packages on MikTex.  This process does not depend on the editor that you use (in this case WinEdit).  [Probably this specific answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55473/14100)

Comment: The problem is WinEdt is bundled with MikTex, and I can't find way to configure it e.g. via start>All Programs>MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: I didn't realize that the two came bundled.  Can you search your system for `miktex-update.exe` or `miktex-update_admin.exe`?

Comment: Winedt never comes bundled with miktex. But it is set by default to work with miktex. If miktex is absent, it will work with texlive also.

Comment: In winedt 6, go to the menu TeX->MiKTeX->MiKTeX Package Manager. In the window that appears, synchronize the packages with a repository and select the package TiKZ and install.

Comment: I select the Tikz package, it says it is not a correct repository,so where can I download the correct tikz package?

Comment: Start the miktex package manager, go the repository menu and change the repository to one which is intact and has no delay (http://www.miktex.org/pkg/repositories). In case you have problems to start the manager from winedt (the links there can be faulty) use the normal windows start menu to find the package manager and miktex settings).