# Installing TikZ and PGF for WinEdt in Windows 7

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, windows, winedt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)

I have tried to follow
http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-05-18.pdf
to install TikZ and PGF for windows, but failed.

I can't really find pgf and xcolor in the udpate manager of MikTex.

Is there any installation guide specifically for this that I can follow?

Comment: A virtually identical question has recently been posted: [how to install Tikz and PGF on WinEdt6.0](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64851/how-to-install-tikz-and-pgf-on-winedt6-0).

Comment: You should use MiKTeX package manager and synchronise with the repositories. Then you will see those packages in the list.

Comment: Thanks, I can't find the package x-color there...
Could it due to the MikTex veresion is not updated, and how should we checked the MikTex version bundled with WinEdt?

Comment: You can't find packages which haven't been installed yet in the *update* manager. Use the *package* manager instead. The packages are called `xcolor` and `pgf`. Or simply enable the on-the-fly installation in miktex settings and then compile a document. Also there is no miktex "bundled" with winedt. winedt has nothing to do with the question if a package is installed or not.