# TikZ Datavisualization example reports "Undefined control sequence", yet still works

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tikz-datavisualization

### The Problem

Reproducing an example from the pgf manual appears to work, yet reports an error.  Does anyone have a guess what the problem is?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \datavisualization [school book axes, all axes={unit length=5mm, ticks={step=2}}, visualize as smooth line]
        data [format=function] {
        var t : interval [0:2*pi];
        func x = \value t * cos(\value t r);
        func y = \value t * sin(\value t r);
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Detail of Error(s)

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence. \pgfutil@font@footnotesize
> ->\footnotesize 
>                                             l.13  };
> ```

and repeated instances of

> ```
> The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message
> was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I'
> and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. \pgfutil@font@footnotesize
> ->\footnotesize 
>                                             l.13  };
> ```

### Systems Tested

Tested on Overleaf and Linux TexStudio.  Both are running PDFLaTeX.

### Similar Problems

[This old issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67146/tikz-datavisualization-example-fails) reports similar errors, but the correct library is called in this question.

Comment: Try with the article class instead of minimal.

Comment: Oof, that was obvious.  Thanks.

Comment: Obvoius if you know that minimal doesn’t define \footnotesize (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/) etc at least ...

Comment: You should add an answer so I can mark it as solved/give you magical internet points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the`minimal`class doesn’t define size changing commands such as `\footnotesize`, just use `article` instead.

This is one of the reasons why `minimal` in general should be avoided, see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)