# up to date check in TikZ external

Tags: tikz-external

I'd like to use the external library with TikZ. There I want to use the "up to date check". But when activating the key in this minimal example I got the error:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/external/up to
>   date check' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

This is the minimal example I used:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
    adieresis={ä},
    germandbls={ß},
    Euro={€},
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[  prefix=figures/
    %, up to date check=md5
    %, force remake
]

\begin{document}

\tikzsetnextfilename{circle}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, circle, minimum width=2cm, red] {};
    \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I updated my MiKTeX distribution, but nothing changes.

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation about that key, where did you read about it exactly?

Comment: I read it in the manual `pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf` (http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) on page 405.

Comment: Will replacing `\tikzsetexternalprefix{figures/, up to date check=md5, force remake}` instead of `\tikzexternalize[ prefix=figures/,up to date check=md5, force remake]` work for you?

Comment: In this case no file output is produced.

Comment: That is the manual of the CVS version, which is not same as the one found in the MikTeX repos. You'll have to download the CVS build from Texample, and install it manually.

Comment: There are some instructions for installing such a build here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2045/586

Comment: I tried to install the current build manually. But the error is the same. Where do I see with `\listfiles` whether my manual installation was successful?

Comment: I get the same error on a current TeXlive (full update literally minutes before I post this). The pgfmanual I see the option described in is from May 2012, so I guess it *should* work by now. Not sure "too localized" is the correct answer here.

Comment: Got it. I installed the build from TeXamples and every thing runs. On my last trial the texhash didn´t get the local files. I still don´t know why, but on the current computer every things works fine. Thx!