# pgfkeys "/handlers/first char syntax" generating error

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I'm trying to follow the example from the `tikz` manual (2.10-CVS development version), but I'm not meeting success.  Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys
  {
    /handlers/first char syntax=true,
    /handlers/first char syntax/the character "/.initial=\hello,
  }
\newcommand{\hello}[1]{Quoted: #1.}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Hello: \pgfkeys{"Does this work"}
\end{document}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfkeys@syntax@handlers ->\pgfutil@ifnextchar 
                                               \relax \pgfkeys@syntax@@handl...
l.8   }

?
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of the docs are you looking at: I don't see `first char syntax` in the PGF v2.10 manual. (I get an error about an unknown key, not the internal one you get.)

Comment: @JosephWright I'm using the 2.10 CVS version copied per the instruction found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63982/22413)

Comment: Use `pgf` instead of `pgfkeys`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\pgfutil@ifnextchar` macro is defined as part of the 'basic utilities' of `pgf` but not as part of the `pgfkeys` code (`pgfkeys.code.tex`). As such, you need to load `pgf` rather than just `pgfkeys` to make this work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfkeys
  {
    /handlers/first char syntax=true,
    /handlers/first char syntax/the character "/.initial=\hello,
  }
\newcommand{\hello}[1]{Quoted: #1.}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Hello: \pgfkeys{"Does this work"}
\end{document}
```

Note that I've had to had modify the `\newcommand` line subtly, compared to the MWE in the question.

---

As the question relates to the *development* version of `pgf`, and as the code comments in `pgfkeys.code.tex` describe it as self-contained, I would regard this as an issue in the code, which should be reported to the developers.

Comment: Reported as https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/249/