# How to clip a rectangle with multiple shapes (circle)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, nodes

How to clip a rectangle with multiple shapes (circle)?
I need to create a complex venn diagram and need to clip the outer rectangle in a shape that is combined with multiple circle. Not sure how to do it. I could do it with one circle though,

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{graphicx, tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\Space{(-5,-5) rectangle (5,5)}
\def\Item{(-1.9,0.62) circle (2.5cm)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(3cm,-5cm)}, fill opacity=1.0]
        \fill [orange, even odd rule] \Space \Item;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Pixelord, welcome to the site! Could you edit your question to turn the code snippet into a complete minimal example document (starting from `\documentclass`)? At the moment, the code sample doesn't really help (what's `\Space`? What's `\Item`? What does the `fill pattern` have to do with the question?)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Paul Gaborit's `invclip` style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59168/2552) for this, using one clipping path per circle:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    invclip/.style={
        clip,
        insert path={{[reset cm](-16383.99999pt,-16383.99999pt) rectangle (16383.99999pt,16383.99999pt)}}
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \path [invclip] (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
        \path [invclip] (1,0.5) circle [radius=0.8cm];
        \path [invclip] (1.2,-0.3) circle [radius=0.8cm];
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \fill [orange] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (2.5,1.5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Jake,I am getting following error while trying your code.


pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tikz/insert path' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \path [invclip] (

Comment: @Pixelord: That sounds like you're using a really outdated version of TikZ. The current one is (and has been for a couple of years) version 2.1

Comment: Yes I guessed so. I am using TexStudio 2.6.2 and not sure how to update the tikZ it is using.

Comment: @Pixelord: That depends on which distribution you're using (MikTeX?). TexStudio is an editor, not a distribution. Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz and the questions linked from there for information on how to update.

Answer (score 2):

This is another alternative where `(\x,\y)` is changeable and different radius is possible by introducing a new variable \z to the circle radius.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\fill[orange] (-1.2,-1.2) rectangle (1.4,1.4);
\begin{scope}
\foreach \x/\y in {0/0.5, -0.3/0, 0.3/0}
{
\filldraw[yellow,opacity=0.5] (\x,\y) circle (0.5 cm);
}
\end{scope}
\node at (0,0.2) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Painting white is often not desirable if you have something lying under the rectangle which is probably why you are clipping anyway.

Comment: @percusse -- Thanks for the comment. Observed and improved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your question, but if it means "how to draw a background rectangle behind several circles?" here you have another option. In this case you don't need to fix a previous size for the rectangle.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[execute at end picture=%
{
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\path[fill=orange]
([shift={(-1mm,-1mm)}]current bounding box.south west) rectangle
([shift={(1mm,1mm)}]current bounding box.north east);
\end{pgfonlayer}
}]
    \fill[white] (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
    \fill[white] (1,0.5) circle [radius=0.8cm];
    \fill[white] (1.2,-0.3) circle [radius=0.8cm];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for helping me find a bug in my package.  Once the fix gets distributed as V3.21, the MWE could be as simple as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
{\color{white}%
\stackinset{l}{.5cm}{b}{1.8cm}{\scalebox{15}{$\bullet$}}{%
\stackinset{l}{1.5cm}{b}{2cm}{\scalebox{15}{$\bullet$}}{%
\stackinset{l}{1.2cm}{b}{0.8cm}{\scalebox{15}{$\bullet$}}{%
\textcolor{orange}{\rule{5cm}{5cm}}%
}%
}}}
\end{document}
```

But in the meantime, until the fix gets propagated, here is the MWE, using the `stackengine` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%\stackinset{l/c/r}{x}{b/c/t}{y}{inset}{anchor}
\renewcommand*\stackinset[6]{%
  \def\conditioned@inset{\stack@delim#5\stack@delim}%
  \def\conditioned@anchor{\stack@delim#6\stack@delim}%
  \ifstrequal{#4}{}%
    {\setlength{\stack@tmplength}{0pt}}%
    {\setlength{\stack@tmplength}{#4}}%
  \if c#3%
    \setlength{\temp@stkl}{%
      \heightof{\conditioned@anchor}+\depthof{\conditioned@anchor}%
      -\heightof{\conditioned@inset}-\depthof{\conditioned@inset}}%
    \addtolength{\stack@tmplength}{.5\temp@stkl}%
  \fi%
  \ifstrequal{#2}{}{\def\stack@tmp{0pt}}{\def\stack@tmp{#2}}%
  \def\stack@lroffset{\rule{\stack@tmp}{0pt}}%
  \addtolength{\stack@tmplength}{%
    \heightof{\conditioned@inset}+\depthof{\conditioned@inset}}%
  \if c#1%
    \def\conditioned@inset{\stack@lroffset\stack@lroffset#5}%
  \else%
    \def\conditioned@inset{\stack@lroffset#5\stack@lroffset}%
  \fi%
  \stackengine{-\stack@tmplength}{#6}{\conditioned@inset}%
              {\inset@valign{#3}}{#1}{\quietstack}{T}{S}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
{\color{white}%
\stackinset{l}{.5cm}{b}{1.8cm}{\scalebox{15}{$\bullet$}}{%
\stackinset{l}{1.5cm}{b}{2cm}{\scalebox{15}{$\bullet$}}{%
\stackinset{l}{1.2cm}{b}{0.8cm}{\scalebox{15}{$\bullet$}}{%
\textcolor{orange}{\rule{5cm}{5cm}}%
}%
}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]