# Transparent clipping - make transparent center in tikz image

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, path-clipping

I have tried to replicate a logo using tikz. As you can see the logo consists of seven triangles in a circle, with concave edges toward the center of the circle.
To do this I have drawn the triangles and superimposed a white circle in the center.
This works, but only if and when the background is white. I would love to make it transparent

I was hoping to use clip coupled with even odd rule to make this work, but that does not appear possible, so I am not sure how to do this in a simple, efficient way.

[image: RFF logo]

```
\definecolor{RFFgray}{HTML}{62615a}
\definecolor{RFFgreen}{HTML}{91b947}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {90,141.4,192.86,244.29,295.71,347.14}
    {
    \draw[fill,RFFgray] (\i:1)--++(122+\i:.5)--($(\i:1)+(\i-122:.5)$)--cycle;
    }    
    \draw[fill,RFFgreen] (38.57:1)--++(122+38.57:.5)--($(38.57:1)+(38.57-122:.5)$)--cycle;
    \draw[white,fill](0,0)circle(.87);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You always can draw only the desired part: the 'triangles'. For example, with a `\pic`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset
{%
  pics/my triangle/.style={%
    code={\path[pic actions] (0:1) -- (180/7:0.87) arc (180/7:-180/7:0.87) -- cycle;}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{RFFgray} {HTML}{62615a}
\definecolor{RFFgreen}{HTML}{91b947}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {1,3,4,...,7}
    \pic[rotate=-360/7+360*\i/7,fill=RFFgray] {my triangle};
  \pic[rotate=360/7,fill=RFFgreen] {my triangle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** As Anis suggests, here you can se the 'transparency'. Of course, there is nothing transparent here. Only what you can see is drawn.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset
{%
  pics/my triangle/.style={%
    code={\path[pic actions] (0:1) -- (180/7:0.87) arc (180/7:-180/7:0.87) -- cycle;}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{example-image-duck}};
  \foreach \i in {1,3,4,...,7}
    \pic[rotate=-360/7+360*\i/7,fill=blue!50] {my triangle};
  \pic[rotate=360/7,fill=red!50] {my triangle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Suggestion to demonstrate the transparency: adding this line of code `\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,rounded corners=1ex}, show background rectangle]` from the tikz manual https://tikz.dev/library-backgrounds#tikz/background:rectangle

Comment: @anis, thanks for the suggestion. Of course, you can draw anything behind as a demonstration, but I think it's not necessary, as there's nothing transparent. Only what you see is drawn.

Comment: Oh it is a ducky!!! <3

Answer (score 4):

[image]

It uses the TikZ command `arc`.  There are two constants `\cR` and `\cA` that controls the dimensions of the triangles in case you need to modify them.

You can modify also the number of triangles.

[image]

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{RFFgray}{HTML}{62615a}
\definecolor{RFFgreen}{HTML}{91b947}


\begin{tikzpicture}[evaluate={%
    integer \N; \N = 7;
    real \r, \cR, \d, \cD;
    \r = 1;
    \cR = .87;
    \cD = .33;
    \d = \cD*360/\N;
  }]
  \fill[violet!50] (-135: \r+.6) rectangle (45: \r+.6);
  \foreach \i [parse=true, evaluate=\i as \a using {(\i -1)*(360/\N) +90}]
  in {1, 2, ..., \N-1}{%
    \filldraw[RFFgray]
    (\a: \r) -- (\a -\d: \r*\cR) arc (\a -\d: \a +\d: \r*\cR) -- (\a: \r);
  }
  \filldraw[RFFgreen]
  (90 -360/\N: \r) -- (90 -360/\N -\d: \r*\cR)
  arc (90 -360/\N -\d: 90 -360/\N +\d: \r*\cR) -- (90 -360/\N: \r);

  \begin{scope}[xshift=2.5cm]
    \foreach \i [parse=true, evaluate=\i as \a using {(\i -1)*(360/\N) +90}]
    in {1, 2, ..., \N-1}{%
      \filldraw[RFFgray]
      (\a: \r) -- (\a -\d: \r*\cR) arc (\a -\d: \a +\d: \r*\cR) -- (\a: \r);
    }
    \filldraw[RFFgreen]
    (90 -360/\N: \r) -- (90 -360/\N -\d: \r*\cR)
    arc (90 -360/\N -\d: 90 -360/\N +\d: \r*\cR) -- (90 -360/\N: \r);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inverted clip, e.g. from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/138918/36296

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%\pagecolor{red}

\tikzset{
    invclip/.style={
        clip, insert path={{(current page.north east) rectangle (current page.south west)}}},
}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{RFFgray}{HTML}{62615a}
\definecolor{RFFgreen}{HTML}{91b947}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
      \path[invclip] (0,0)circle(.87);
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \foreach \i in {90,141.4,192.86,244.29,295.71,347.14}
    {
    \draw[fill,RFFgray] (\i:1)--++(122+\i:.5)--($(\i:1)+(\i-122:.5)$)--cycle;
    }    
    \draw[fill,RFFgreen] (38.57:1)--++(122+38.57:.5)--($(38.57:1)+(38.57-122:.5)$)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]