# Tikz drawing different type of arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I am new to the TikZ package, and I need to make this image:

[image]

in TikZ.

For now I've done this, and I'm having trouble doing that kind of arrows of image above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    big dot/.style={
            circle, inner sep=0pt, 
            minimum size=3mm, fill=gray
    },
    line/.style={
        draw, 
        line width=1.4pt
    },
        input/.style={
                draw,
                trapezium,
                trapezium left angle=60,
                trapezium right angle=120,
        line width=1.2pt,
        fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}
        },
    obstacle/.style={
                draw,
                trapezium,
                trapezium left angle=120,
                trapezium right angle=60,
        line width=1.2pt,
        fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}
        }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[input](goal1) at (0,0) {GOAL};
\node[input](goal2) at (4,0) {GOAL};
\node[obstacle](obstacle1) at (0,-1.5) {OBSTACLE};
\node[input](goal3) at (1.5,-3) {GOAL};
\node[input](goal4) at (4,-3) {GOAL};

\draw[line] (goal1.east) -- (goal2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The flash is best done with the `decorations.markings` library and drawn manually (there is no arrow that looks like that). The yellow circle is best done as a separate node. The other arrows are tricky because they are filled and relatively large. Are you by any chance using the CVS version of TikZ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very easily done with the new `arrows.meta` library of the CVS version of TikZ (see [How to install a current version of TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2044/16595)).

Unfortunately, I cannot create a *filled* arrow tip of the `stealth` kind (which can be created with the `markings` library by first adding a big black tip and then drawing a smaller arrow tip that is colored in over the black one) *and* the `|` before it. For reference I used:

```
arrowS/.style={postaction=decorate,decoration={name=markings, arrow/.list={#1}}},
/pgf/decoration/arrow/.style args={#1:#2-#3}{mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[#2]{#3}}}
```

which can be used as

```
arrowS={+-0.01pt:scale=1.7-stealth, +-1.5pt:yellow-stealth}
```

which worked for my CVS version but the `|` did not show up. With the stable `2.10` release the `|` worked but the black `stealth` tip wasn’t scaled.

You will need to compromise here without using the `arrows.meta` library.

The `flash` is simply drawn by the `markings` library, you can adjust the values, of course.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  big dot/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3mm, fill=yellow},
  input/.style={draw, trapezium, trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120,
    line width=1.2pt, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}},
  obstacle/.style={draw, trapezium, trapezium left angle=120, trapezium right angle=60,
    line width=1.2pt, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}},
  flash/.style args={#1:#2}{postaction=decorate,decoration={name=markings,
    mark=at position #1 with {%
    \draw[fill=#2, line width=.75\pgflinewidth, line cap=round, line join=round]
         (+\pgflinewidth,+7\pgflinewidth)   -- ++ ( left:+2\pgflinewidth) 
      -- (+-4\pgflinewidth,+-\pgflinewidth) -- ++ (right:+5\pgflinewidth)
      -- (+-\pgflinewidth,+-7\pgflinewidth) -- ++ (right:+2\pgflinewidth)
      -- (+4\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)    -- ++ (left:+5\pgflinewidth) -- cycle;}}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,
  StealthFill/.tip={Stealth[line width=1pt, scale=1.5]}, arrows={[round]}]
\node[input]    (goal1)     at (0,0) {GOAL};
\node[input]    (goal2)     at (4,0) {GOAL};
\node[obstacle] (obstacle1) at (0,-1.5) {OBSTACLE};
\node[input]    (goal3)     at (1.5,-3) {GOAL};
\node[input]    (goal4)     at (4,-3) {GOAL};

\path (goal2) -- node[big dot] (bigdot) {} (goal4);
\path[line width=1.4pt, line cap=rect]
  (goal1) edge[flash=.5:red] (goal2)
  (bigdot) edge (goal3.north)
           edge (goal4)          
           edge[-{StealthFill[fill=yellow]}] (goal2)
  [bend left=10, StealthBar/.style={-{Bar[sep=2] StealthFill[fill=#1]}}]
    (goal2)     edge[StealthBar=green] (obstacle1)
    (obstacle1) edge[StealthBar=red]   (goal2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]