# tikz - drawing a timeline with intervals

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to obtain a tikz picture that looks like the following.
Can you help me to complete my code to achieve that result?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[x=50]
       \draw (-0.2,0) -- (1.2,0);      
       \draw (0, 0) node[below=7pt] {$a_1$};
       \draw[] (0,-0.1) -- (0,0.1);
       \draw (1, 0) node[below=7pt] {$a_2$};       
       \draw[] (1,-0.1) -- (1,0.1);
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**

I like @Qrrbrbirlbel's proposal, but I would like to make the "[" and ")" symbols a little bit larger. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can adjust the size to what you prefer (update removes a superfluous line, left-over from initial code).

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % better to have fontenc *before* inputenc
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw (-0.2,0) -- (1.2,0); 
       \draw [thick] (0.1,-.25) -- (0,-.25) -- (0,.25) -- (0.1,.25);     
       \draw (0,-.25) node [anchor=north] {$a_1$};
       \draw (1,-.25) node [anchor=north] {$a_2$};       
       \draw [thick] (0.7,-.25) .. controls (1.05,-0.2) and (1.05,0.2)
                                .. (0.7,.25);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: tikz exercise]

Answer (score 5):

I’d just use arrow tips here.

For bigger arrow tips, you need to increase the line width.

You can also use the `decorations.markings` library with the `\arrow` macro customized with a scaling (only `yscale` or `xscale` works, too) or other options to place “arrows” on the line.

It is also possible to just add textual content to the line, say a `[` and a `)` where you have control over font (sizes, series, etc.) and you can also scale the node if necessary.

The `arrows.meta` library from the CVS version of TikZ (see [How to install a current version of TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2044/16595)) allows us to do this very easily with `arrows={[scale=2]}` (or any option whatsoever). It is also possible to give options to the arrow tip directly, say

```
\draw [{Bracket[right,red]}-{Arc Barb[arc=270]}] …;
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border={0pt 0pt 0pt 6pt}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% CVS
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=+0pt]
  \draw (+0pt,+0pt) -- ++(right:+10pt) coordinate (@);
  \draw[[-)] (@) node[below=+6pt] {$a_1$} -- ++ (right:+50pt) node[below=+6pt] {$a_2$} coordinate (@);
  \draw (@) -- ++ (right:+10pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz[inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, nodes={below=+6pt}]
  \draw[decoration={
    markings, mark=at position .2 with {\arrow[line width=.7\pgflinewidth,scale=2]{[}},
              mark=at position .8 with {\arrow[line width=.7\pgflinewidth,scale=2]{)}}},
        postaction=decorate]
    (+0pt,+0pt) -- node[pos=.2, below=+3pt] {$a_1$} node[pos=.8, below=+3pt] {$a_2$} ++(right:+70pt);


\tikz[label position=below, inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, every label/.style={font=},
  label distance=+3pt, nodes={font=\bfseries}]
  \draw (+0pt,+0pt) -- node[pos=.2,label=$a_1$] {[} node[pos=.8,label=$a_2$] {)} ++(right:+70pt);

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=+0pt, arrows={[scale=2]}]% CVS
  \draw (+0pt,+0pt) -- ++(right:+10pt) coordinate (@);
  \draw[Bracket-Arc Barb] (@) node[below=+6pt] {$a_1$} -- ++ (right:+50pt) node[below=+6pt] {$a_2$} coordinate (@);
  \draw (@) -- ++ (right:+10pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I like it very much. Is it easy to make the "[" and ")" symbols a little bit larger?

Comment: @user7064 Sorry, I somehow missed your comment. I have updated my answer with a few ideas. Apart from just drawing the symbols yourself as in [another answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142747/16595), there are a few options.

Answer (score 2):

262 keystrokes (compared to the existing answer with 299 keystrokes) with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,1)
    \pstGeonode[PointName={a_1,a_2},PosAngle=-90,PointSymbol=none](1.2,.6){A}(3.8,.6){B}
    \pcline[nodesep=-1](A)(B)
    \psline{[-)}(A)(B)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you want to get a bigger `[` and `)`, I modified the above code as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,1)
    \pstGeonode[PointName={a_1,a_2},PosAngle=-90,PointSymbol=none,PointNameSep=13pt](1.2,.65){A}(3.8,.65){B}
    \pcline[nodesep=-1](A)(B)
    \psline[arrowscale=2]{[-)}(A)(B)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]