# Help drawing a very simple number line using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a very simple number line, i found some code that got me started [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=6248). I have modified the code to get the following picture

[image]

The problem is that I want  the numbers below the line to show up as {-3,2,1,0,1,2,3} but I can't figure out how to modify the following code to do this.

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-] (-6.5,0) -- (6.5,0) ;
\draw[-latex] (-6.5,0) -- (6.5,0) ;
\foreach \x in  {-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] 
{$\x$};
\draw[*-o] (0.92,0) -- (2.08,0);
\draw[very thick    ] (0.92,0) -- (1.92,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

It would nice if I could just divide `\x` by 2 in place of `node[below] 
    {$\x$}`, but I don't know how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Change `{-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6}` to `{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}`

Comment: I didn't mean to write  \x2= int(mod(\x +2,3)) in the middle of the code. I deleted it now.

Comment: Similar visualization: [\[1\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140984/16595); different visualization: [\[2\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142532/16595), [\[3\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144532/16595).

Comment: You can use `$\pgfmathprint{int(\x/2)}$` as node text. By the way, why don't you put the `node` part in the first loop and remove the second one entirely? If you want to follow @azetina's comment, you can use `{-3,...,3}` but with `x=2cm` or `xscale=2`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You should post an answer so the OP can learn different methods. Mine is minimal.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks, `$\pgfmathprint{int(\x/2)}$` is the functionality I was looking for. I combined the first and second loop now. I am very new to this, thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-latex] (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0) ; %edit here for the axis
\foreach \x in  {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3} % edit here for the vertical lines
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3} % edit here for the numbers
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] 
{$\x$};
\draw[*-o] (0.92,0) -- (2.08,0);
\draw[very thick] (0.92,0) -- (1.92,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is something that can work for now with the scaling:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
\draw[very thick] (1,0) -- (2,0);
\path [draw=black, fill=black] (1,0) circle (2pt);
\path [draw=black, fill=white, thick] (2,0.0) circle (2pt);
\draw[latex-latex] (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0) ;
\foreach \x in  {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] 
{$\x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: How about if I want to make more space between each number?

Comment: @JimmyJackson Well the way you have defined the intervals on the number line will look weird if you make it bigger.

Comment: `scale` will scale everything including small circle and ticks ;)

Comment: @HarishKumar Yeah I know, I warned the OP about it.

Comment: For scaling, you can also use `\pgfsetxvec{\pgfpoint{2.5cm}{0cm}}` (as documented on p.290 of the [tikzpgf manual](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf)), which will scale dimensionless x-coordinates. You need to adjust your `.92` and `2.08`, however.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{xunit=15mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-.5)(3,.5)
    \psaxes[yAxis=false,ticksize=0 -4pt]{<->}(0,0)(-3,-1)(3,1)
    \psline[linecolor=blue,arrowscale=1.25]{o-*}(.5,0)(2,0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]