# How to create this simple line in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I just want to know how can I create this simple line in tikz. I found many example but they are too complicated for me to understand. [image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.2]
\draw (0,0) -- (6,0); 
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt, 1pt) node[below] 
{$t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4, t_5$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried or what is too complicated for you.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this is tikz. I am very beginner for this.

Comment: See here, for a starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148252/help-drawing-a-very-simple-number-line-using-tikz?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were almost there; you should only change the node text according to the `\foreach` index.

`\foreach` is a cycle for the variable `\x` from 1 to 5, step 1 (the step is given by the difference between the first and the second element here `{1,2,...,5}`, you don't need to list all the elements, `tikz` computes them for you).

`shift={(\x,0)}` means that the `\draw` is shifted by `\x` along the horizontal axis, you could also use `xshift=\x cm` where `cm` could be replaced by any unit of measure you prefer.

`node[below=2ex] {$t_\x$}` write a node, with text `$t_\x$` (`\x` is automatically replaced), 2ex below the path.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure} 
        \centering 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (6,0); 
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}
            \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,-4pt) -- (0pt, 4pt) node[below=2ex] 
            {$t_\x$};
        \end{tikzpicture}  
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: Second OP's request.

Instead of writing the node text while you were drawing the path, you could name the nodes with `node (t\x) {}`, where `t\x` is the name (`\x` is automatically replaced) and, then, refer to these names to position your labels.

The tikzlibrary `positioning` allows you to decide where and at which distance to position a node w.r.t. another. For example `\node[below=2ex of t5] {$t$};` means "position the node 2ex below of the node named `t5`".

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure} 
        \centering 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (6,0); 
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}
        {\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,-4pt) -- (0pt, 4pt) node (t\x) {};}
        \node[below=2ex of t5] {$t$};
        \node[below=2ex of t1] {$t- \Delta t$};
        \end{tikzpicture}  
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As the OP probably did not fully understand the code, you might want to explain what it does.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks. But I wanted to know, can I replace foreach with custom name for every tick like {t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4, t_5}

Comment: @CarLaTeX In next diagram I need to used only two tick one is $t$ and second is $t + \Delta t$. So, I can not use foreach that.

Comment: @Neeraj I'm happy of that, thank you for accepting my answer, I'll go on with the explanations.

Comment: @CarLaTex why should i not accept your answer when it provide exactly what I wanted. I try my best to upvote every question and answer that I check on tex.stackexchange.

Answer (score 5):

Since you asked for means to use a list for the labels, you might use the following for that. I think `pgf` has a built in mechanism for arrays, but I don't remember the macro names...

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setupmylabellist}[1]{%
  \count255 = 0\relax%
  \@for\x:=#1\do{
    \expandafter\edef\csname mylabel\the\count255\endcsname{\x}
    \advance\count255 by 1\relax%
  }
}
\newcommand{\usemylabel}[1]{\csname mylabel#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick,
]
\setupmylabellist{foo1,bar1,baz1,foo2,bar2,baz2}
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5}
\draw [shift={(\x,0)}] (0.1,0.2) -- + (0,-0.4) node[below] {\usemylabel{\x}};
%
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- node[below=8mm] {X axis title} + (5.2,0);
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]