# Drawing a number line with fractional points

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

How can I draw following number line using tikz?

[image]

I tried taking help of [Help drawing a very simple number line using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148252/help-drawing-a-very-simple-number-line-using-tikz) but when I input numbers, they are drawn very close to each other. Any hint would be highly appreciated

Comment: We need to see what code you actually use and which numbers you write in. You probably want to do something like `x = 4cm` to scale the *xyz* coordinate system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[latex-latex] (-.2,0)--(10.5,0);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,10}
        \draw[line width=2pt] (\x,.1)--(\x,-.1) node[below] {\bfseries $\frac{\x}{4}$};
        \filldraw (7,0) circle(.1) node[above] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**ADD**: If You want losenges as marks consider this code;

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[latex-latex] (-.5,0)--(10.5,0);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,10}{
        \draw[line width=2pt] (\x,-.1) node[below] {\bfseries $\frac{\x}{4}$};
        \node at (\x,0) {\small $\blacklozenge$};
    }
        \node at (7,.35) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]