# Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) error when using \foreach with node[pos]

Tags: positioning, nodes, foreach

I am trying to draw a path and position nodes on it and fill them using this code and it works

```
\documentclass[varwidth=20cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [dotted](0,0)--(2.5,0.5)
  node(2)[pos=0.1]{} node(3)[pos=0.2]{} node(4)[pos=0.3]{} node(5)[pos=0.4]{} node(6)[pos=0.5]{} node(7)[pos=0.6]{} node(8)[pos=0.7]{} node(9)[pos=0.8]{}  node(1)[pos=0.9]{} node(10)[pos=1]{};
%  \draw [red,dotted] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0.1) (2,0.3) (2.5,0.5)};

  \fill (1) circle[radius=1pt];
  \fill (2) circle[radius=1pt];
  \fill (3) circle[radius=1pt];
  \fill (4) circle[radius=1pt];
  \fill (5) circle[radius=1pt];
  \fill (6) circle[radius=1pt];
  \fill (7) circle[radius=1pt];
  \fill (8) circle[radius=1pt];
  \fill (9) circle[radius=1pt];
  \fill (10)circle[radius=1pt];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, i want to make it more efficient and not to repeat the same line of code 10 times by using `\foreach`. I stared by this piece of code put it gives this error **Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)**

```
\documentclass[varwidth=20cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [dotted](0,0)--(2.5,0.5)
  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x] in {1,2,...,10}
    node(\x) [pos={\x/10}]{}
    \fill (\x) circle[radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, i am still wanting to draw the nodes on the path not by their own.

Comment: Which version of tikz are you using? Insert `\listfiles` in your preamble and read out the log. I do not get the error you are getting.

Comment: What is the expected output when using `\listfiles`, i put it and nothing changed in the log.

Comment: it should show the version of tikz and pgf. You have to use the first example to get it written in your log. (full compilable).

Comment: ahaaa, okay.
 tikz.sty    2012/08/29 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.100)

 pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.12)

Comment: OK, you could update your system to version 3.0 and try Claudios answer which will work for sure.

Comment: I used the answer of this Q : [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz) and download the latest tikz build. Is there any way to do the update?.

Comment: Please have a look on how to update MikTeX or TeXlive. Whatever you are using. Do not do it manually if you do not have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems are two basically:

1. The `\foreach` needs braces if there are more than one operation to be performed;
2. It is not possible to use `\draw` and `\fill` in the same path.

The point n.2 is the most important: what one does while using a `\foreach` statement inside a `\draw`n path is to append things. Of course it is possible to append nodes, but it is not possible, in the same statement, to add nodes and fill circles drawn as a separate path.

The explanation suggests there is a simpler way to make it: nodes can be filled themselves, so why not use this possibility?

An example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [dotted](0,0)--(2.5,0.5)
  \foreach \x in {1,2,...,10}{
    node[fill,circle,inner sep=0.75pt](\x) [pos={\x/10}]{}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used `node` before adding `fill` and the same error occurred. This code also gives the same error. But thanks for the node filling tip.

Comment: @Misaki: Did you compile the exact code of mine?

Comment: Yes i did. same error.

Comment: @Misaki: I really don't see why it should not compile, even with previous version of TikZ 2.10. Do you have the 2.10 version or the new 3.0.0?

Comment: `tikz.sty    2012/08/29 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.100)`
`pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.12)`