# Why can't I load the tikz-cd package?

Tags: packages, tikz-cd

I'm having trouble getting the `tikz-cd` package working. My MWE is

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

This results in an error

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 17, version
           `2013/12/13' of package tikz,
           but only version
           `2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)'
           is available.

(/home/babadook/texmf/tex/generic/tikz-cd/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarymatrix.co    de.tex)
! I can't find file `tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex'.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex
                                              \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.18 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,quotes,arrows.meta}

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex
                                              \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.18 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,quotes,arrows.meta}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on foo.log.

LaTeX exited abnormally with code 1 at Tue Mar 31 13:13:42
```

It looks like I'm using a dated version of `tikz` but I'm not sure how to update the package.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: is this error message from the minimal code you give above?

Comment: get the package from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/ extract it it have TDS form :tex\latex\pgf tex\generic\pgf ... each of them go to the equivalent in your installation than texhash

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. Or does your compilation stop? If you are not able to update your Ti*k*Z files, you should try to work with your current set-up. If you are getting real errors, you should ask here again.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the question with the full error message. I am not getting any output written.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Well, you will have to update than. Or if you can't do that, get an older version of `tikz-cd` which does not require those new libraries of Ti*k*Z. Or try to find the code of the library `quotes` and copy it into your version of `tikz-cd` replacing the call of `\usetikzlibrary{quotes}`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi How would I go about updating?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick By reading this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2044

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Is your problem solved?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi no it isn't

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you have downloaded the most recent version of `tikz-cd` and stored it in your personal tree, under `~/texmf`. However, this version of `tikz-cd` requires a more recent version of `tikz` than you have on your system and it fails because it needs files that are absent from that `tikz` distribution.

You could download also TikZ version 3.0.0; however this will probably open other problems because packages have several interdependencies.

You should upgrade your TeX distribution at least to TeX Live 2014, which will already contain the version of `tikz-cd` you need. If Ubuntu doesn't provide it, install the “vanilla” version. See [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) and the excellent answer by Silke, that can be easily modified for the present version that's 2015.

Comment: This may be the correct answer, but I installed the latest 2015 version, but it still seems to be using the old version...