# ! LaTeX Error: File `multirow.sty' not found

Tags: texmaker, mactex

I am using Basictex on my mac, and using TEXMAKER as editor. I installed multirow package by

```
 tlmgr install multirow
```

command. And output is

```
 tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet
 tlmgr install: package already present: multirow
```

Its showing this error ! LaTeX Error: File `multirow.sty' not found.

I really do not know what is happening. Any kind of help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid your write-up isn't very clear. Specifically, what is the "it" in "It[']s showing this error"? What is returned if you type `kpsewhich multirow.sty` at a terminal prompt? Incidentally, what's your reason for installing Basictex rather than the full MacTeX installation?

Comment: @Mico, thanks for your quick reply. I am writing a project document. i I started downloading MacTex but somehow it shows network error, then i switched to Basictex, We [class mates] are writing document together. I took a file and tried to modify then its showing this error.`kpsewhich multirow.sty`  at terminal showing  /`usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty`

Comment: Since `kpsewhich` is able to find `multirow.sty` -- in the directory where it should be, no less -- it's puzzling that you're not able to load it via a `\usepackage{multirow}` statement. Maybe something else went wrong during installation of BasicTeX? All I can suggest at this point is to try to re-install BasicTeX from scratch.

Comment: Okay. Suggestion is taken. Should is still try to install MacTex!

Answer (score 8):

On Linux this should work fine, if you install the package `texlive-latex-extra`

The Documentation is huge (some GB) and is not needed locally, so installation without docs via aptitude would be

```
aptitude install texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-recommended-doc_ texlive-pictures-doc_ texlive-latex-base-doc_ texlive-pstricks-doc_ texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-extra-doc_ texlive-fonts-recommended-doc_
```

Comment: This answer helps for other packages as well, it solved the `! LaTeX Error: File ``tikz.sty' not found` error for me.

Answer (score 5):

On Arch Linux based distributions, this package is called `texlive-latexextra` in the standard repository.

```
sudo pacman -S texlive-latexextra
```

Answer (score 4):

Using **Texlive Package Manager**, install `collection-latexextra` with the following command:

```
tlmgr install collection-latexextra
```

Comment: I installed that and it didn't solve the problem

Comment: is this still not solved??

Comment: it worked for me with collection-latexextra

Answer (score 3):

On Fedora:

```
$ dnf provides */multirow.sty
```

texlive-multirow-9:svn58396-45.fc35.noarch : Create tabular cells spanning multiple rows
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty

texlive-multirow-9:svn58396-48.fc35.noarch : Create tabular cells spanning multiple rows
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty

```
$ sudo dnf install texlive-multirow
```

Comment: `dnf install "tex(multirow.sty)"` also works

Answer (score 0):

On a MAC when I recently hit this problem I needed to uninstall `texlive` and `basictex` and install instead `mactex`

```
brew uninstall texlive 
brew uninstall basictex
brew install mactex
```

Comment: I don't know what `brew` is doing, but MacTeX *is* TeX Live (for Mac).

Comment: ah really? now I'm really confused, brew install texlive works as well, but only when I used mactex did the multirow.sty error go away. should I delete my answer do you think? (ps: all my packages were up to date, so it isn't the case that I was reinstalling a newer version of the same package).

Comment: Like I said, I don't know what `brew` does or what it puts in `texlive`.

Comment: well apparently not multirow ;-)

Comment: Indeed ;). Very strange, but distributions call different mixtures different things. Perhaps the Brew Gods don't like tables!