# Beamer and tikz globally and locally installed

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am using lyx and want to crate a Beamer presentation with flowcharts.

But I want to make the aspect ratio to be 19:6. The last version of the Beamer package supports this, but older ones, not.

In my system, the older one is installed. So, I have installed locally the newer one (along with all required packages, including pgf, that in turn includes tikz).

This works fine and I can produce beamer presentations with 19:6 aspect ratio.

But now, I want to add some flowcharts. For this purpose, I load the package tikz. But when I attempt to compile I get the following errors:

> LaTeX Error: Command \pgfdeclareimage already defined.
>
> LaTeX Error: Command \pgfdeclaremask already defined.
>
> LaTeX Error: Command \pgfimage already defined.

And I think that Latex loads twice the pgf package.
So, how could I prevent latex from loading the older (globally installed) packages without to delete them (I do not have root permissions).

But it seems to work well when only the beamer package is loaded, which is also installed globally and locally).

The latex code follows. I have generated it from lyx with Export->LaTeX(pdflatex), and get the same errors as within lyx when I run the file with pdflatex:

```
%% LyX 2.1.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
 % this default might be overridden by plain title style
 \newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
 % (ERT) argument for the TOC
 \AtBeginDocument{%
   \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
   \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
   \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
 }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you show a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that produces this warning? Beamer internally already loads (parts of) `pgf`.

Comment: Sorry, it is now there.

Comment: This looks fine. To circumvent the installation problem, would a portable installation work for you? This basically means that texlive can be placed on a flash drive or some other folder. (we have instructions on this site for different operating systems, what do you use?) Or maybe an online compiler such as overleaf or sharelatex?

Comment: How/where did you install pgf yourself? Maybe it has to be put into another folder, see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/85Z8kICOdow/yKMQQ6pLSTcJ

Comment: The solution in the thread posted by @samcarter has worked!

Comment: Good to hear! Have fun with beamer and tikz :)

Comment: @samcarter Is there a duplicate or do you want to answer?

Comment: @cfr I asked @ UlrikeFischer in chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42356262#42356262 about an answer, she prefers to vote as unclear. Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz would do as duplicate? (I am not voting myself, as this would close the question right away)

Comment: @samcarter That will happen if I vote, too, unfortunately. Unless we go with the unclear suggestion.

Comment: @cfr I decided to go the duplicate route.